# PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct-on

I want to run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) purchases.address_id, purchases.*
FROM purchases
WHERE purchases.product_id = 1
ORDER BY purchases.purchased_at DESC
```

But I get this error:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Adding `address_id` as first `ORDER BY` expression silences the error, but I really don't want to add sorting over `address_id`. Is it possible to do without ordering by `address_id`?

Comment: Your order clause has purchased_at not address_id.Can you make your question clear.

Comment: my order has purchase because i want it, but postgres also asks for address(see error message).

Comment: Fully answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796078/selecting-rows-ordered-by-some-column-and-disctinct-on-another

Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/users/268273/mosty-mostacho

Comment: Personally I think requiring DISTINCT ON to match ORDER BY is very questionable, as there are a variety of legitimate use cases for having them differ. There is a post on postgresql.uservoice trying to change this for those who feel similarly. https://postgresql.uservoice.com/forums/21853-general/suggestions/713352-allow-select-distinct-on-a-from-t-order-by-b

Comment: got the exact same issue, and facing the same limtation.  At the moment I have broken it into a sub-query and then ordering, but it feels dirty.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Documentation says:

> DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. [...] Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first. [...] The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s).

[Official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

So you'll have to add the `address_id` to the order by.

Alternatively, if you're looking for the full row that contains the most recent purchased product for each `address_id` and that result sorted by `purchased_at` then you're trying to solve a greatest N per group problem which can be solved by the following approaches:

The general solution that should work in most DBMSs:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM purchases t1
JOIN (
    SELECT address_id, max(purchased_at) max_purchased_at
    FROM purchases
    WHERE product_id = 1
    GROUP BY address_id
) t2
ON t1.address_id = t2.address_id AND t1.purchased_at = t2.max_purchased_at
ORDER BY t1.purchased_at DESC
```

A more PostgreSQL-oriented solution based on @hkf's answer:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) *
  FROM purchases 
  WHERE product_id = 1
  ORDER BY address_id, purchased_at DESC
) t
ORDER BY purchased_at DESC
```

Problem clarified, extended and solved here: [Selecting rows ordered by some column and distinct on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796078)

Comment: It works, but gives wrong ordering. That's why i want to get rid of address_id in order clause

Comment: But may be there is another way to select latest purchases for disticnt addresses?

Comment: You have to order over address_id, but this works if you order by `purchases.purchased_at DESC` because for each address, it grabs the most recent purchase.

Comment: If you need to order by purchases.purchased_at, you can add purchased_at to your DISTINCT conditions: `SELECT DISTINCT ON (purchases.purchased_at, address_id)`. However, two records with the same address_id but different purchased_at values will result in duplicates in the returned set. Make sure you are cognizant of the data you're querying.

Comment: The spirit of the question is clear. No need to pick on semantics. It's sad that the accepted and most voted answer doesn't help you solve the problem.

Comment: This query, though accepted, does not produce the desired ordering in the result (with `ORDER BY purchases.purchased_at DESC`).

Comment: Your fix is not based on [hkf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795711/939860), which is incorrect and misleading. [It happens to be an exact copy of what I posted 5 years ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796104/939860)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I did base it on hkf's answer. The issue is that your answer happens to be the same as hkf's (except for the ordering, of course). Regarding the ordering, you have suggested me to use the improvement for the ORDER BY in your comment above, so I improved the answer with your own feedback. I'm not sure what's the matter with that. Anyway, feel free to edit my answer as you deem appropriate

Comment: @MostyMostacho: It's not the same, and it's not just the ordering. That's the point.

Comment: Here is a postgresql.uservoice post trying to lift this limitation for those that agree it is a questionable limitation. https://postgresql.uservoice.com/forums/21853-general/suggestions/713352-allow-select-distinct-on-a-from-t-order-by-b

Comment: as someone suggested in the other answer, the more generic database solution will return two rows with the same `address_id` for the same `purchased_at`

Comment: "The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression" But why though? It should suffice to order on purchased_at since that will put the desired row at the top of the group.

Answer (score 99):

A **subquery** can solve it:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) *
    FROM   purchases
    WHERE  product_id = 1
    ) p
ORDER  BY purchased_at DESC;
```

Leading expressions in `ORDER BY` have to agree with columns in `DISTINCT ON`, so you can't order by different columns in the same `SELECT`.

Only use an additional `ORDER BY` in the subquery if you want to pick a particular row from each set:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) *
    FROM   purchases
    WHERE  product_id = 1
    ORDER  BY address_id, purchased_at DESC  -- get "latest" row per address_id
    ) p
ORDER  BY purchased_at DESC;
```

If `purchased_at` can be `NULL`, use `DESC NULLS LAST` - and match your index for best performance. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- [Why does ORDER BY NULLS LAST affect the query plan on a primary key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254761/3684)

Related, with more explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Comment: You cannot use `DISTINCT ON` without a matching `ORDER BY`. The first query requires an `ORDER BY address_id` inside the subquery.

Comment: @AristotlePagaltzis: But you *can*. Wherever you got that from, it's incorrect. You can use `DISTINCT ON` without `ORDER BY` in the same query. You get an arbitrary row from each set of peers defined by the `DISTINCT ON` clause in this case. Try it or follow the links above for details and links to the manual. `ORDER BY` in the same query (the same `SELECT`) just cannot disagree with `DISTINCT ON`. I did explain that, too.

Comment: Huh, you’re right. I was blind to the implication of the “unpredictable unless `ORDER BY` is used” note in the docs because it does not make sense to me that the feature is implemented to be able deal with non-consecutive sets of values… yet won’t allow you to exploit that with an explicit ordering. Annoying.

Comment: @AristotlePagaltzis: That's because, internally, Postgres uses one of (at least) *two* distinct algorithms: either traverse a sorted list or work with hash values - whichever promises to be faster. In the later case the result is not sorted by `DISTINCT ON` expressions (yet).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your second query solved my issue and returns results in expected order!

Answer (score 72):

You can order by address_id in an subquery, then order by what you want in an outer query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) purchases.address_id, purchases.* 
    FROM "purchases" 
    WHERE "purchases"."product_id" = 1 ORDER BY address_id DESC ) 
ORDER BY purchased_at DESC
```

Comment: But this will be slower than just one query, no?

Comment: Very marginally yes. Although since you have a purchases.* in your original `select`, I don't think this is production code?

Comment: I'd add that for newer versions of postgres you need to alias the subquery. For example: SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) purchases.address_id, purchases.* FROM "purchases" WHERE "purchases"."product_id" = 1 ORDER BY address_id DESC ) AS tmp ORDER BY tmp.purchased_at DESC

Comment: This would return `address_id` twice (without need). Many clients have problems with duplicate column names. `ORDER BY address_id DESC` is pointless and misleading. It does nothing useful in this query. The result is an arbitrary pick from each set of rows with the same `address_id`, not the row with the latest `purchased_at`. The ambiguous question did not ask for that explicitly, but that's almost certainly the OP's intention. In short: ***do not use this query***. I posted alternatives with explanation.

Comment: Worked for me. Great answer.

Comment: this does not sort it by `purchased_at` in a subquery at all, it will return just randomly ordered rows of distinct `addres_id`s

Answer (score 12):

Window function may solve that in one pass:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) 
   LAST_VALUE(purchases.address_id) OVER wnd AS address_id
FROM "purchases"
WHERE "purchases"."product_id" = 1
WINDOW wnd AS (
   PARTITION BY address_id ORDER BY purchases.purchased_at DESC
   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

Comment: It would be nice if someone explained the query.

Comment: @Gajus: Short explanation: it doesn't work, only returns distinct `address_id`. The principle *could* work, though. Related examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064571/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/11533808/939860. But there are shorter and / or faster queries for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone using [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/), this worked for me

```
from app import db
from app.models import Purchases
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
from sqlalchemy import desc

stmt = Purchases.query.distinct(Purchases.address_id).subquery('purchases')
alias = aliased(Purchases, stmt)
distinct = db.session.query(alias)
distinct.order_by(desc(alias.purchased_at))
```

Comment: Yes, or even easier, I was able to use: `query.distinct(foo).from_self().order(bar)`

Comment: @LaurentMeyer do you mean `Purchases.query`?

Comment: Yes, I meant Purchases.query

Comment: That's weird, is `from_self` something undocumented? I cannot get it to work – `Query` and `QuerySet` raise AttributeError when I try to access it

Comment: Oh, wait, it's SQLAlchemy, not Django, silly me

Answer (score 0):

It can also be solved using the following query along with other answers.

```
WITH purchase_data AS (
        SELECT address_id, purchased_at, product_id,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY address_id ORDER BY purchased_at DESC) AS row_number
        FROM purchases
        WHERE product_id = 1)
SELECT address_id, purchased_at, product_id
FROM purchase_data where row_number = 1
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also done this by using group by clause

```
   SELECT purchases.address_id, purchases.* FROM "purchases"
    WHERE "purchases"."product_id" = 1 GROUP BY address_id,
purchases.purchased_at ORDER purchases.purchased_at DESC
```

Comment: This is incorrect (unless `purchases` has only the two columns `address_id` and `purchased_at`). Because of `GROUP BY`, you will need to use an aggregate function to get the value of each column not used for grouping, so they values will all be coming from different rows of the group unless you go through ugly and inefficient gymnastics. This can be fixed only by using window functions rather than `GROUP BY`.