# Selecting rows ordered by some column and distinct on another

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

Related to - [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-without-ordering)

I have table purchases (product_id, purchased_at, address_id)

Sample data:

```
| id | product_id |   purchased_at    | address_id |
| 1  |     2      | 20 Mar 2012 21:01 |     1      |
| 2  |     2      | 20 Mar 2012 21:33 |     1      |
| 3  |     2      | 20 Mar 2012 21:39 |     2      |
| 4  |     2      | 20 Mar 2012 21:48 |     2      |
```

The result I expect is the most recent purchased product (full row) for each address_id and that result must be sorted in descendant order by the purchased_at field:

```
| id | product_id |   purchased_at    | address_id |
| 4  |     2      | 20 Mar 2012 21:48 |     2      |
| 2  |     2      | 20 Mar 2012 21:33 |     1      |
```

Using query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) purchases.address_id, purchases.*
FROM "purchases"
WHERE "purchases"."product_id" = 2
ORDER BY purchases.address_id ASC, purchases.purchased_at DESC
```

I'm getting:

```
| id | product_id |   purchased_at    | address_id |
| 2  |     2      | 20 Mar 2012 21:33 |     1      |
| 4  |     2      | 20 Mar 2012 21:48 |     2      |
```

So the rows is same, but order is wrong. Any way to fix it?

Comment: (Better) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9795660/939860

Comment: Not a duplicate tho :) Just more correct question. On previous post I got clear answer - "No" :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Quite a clear question :)

```
SELECT t1.* FROM purchases t1
LEFT JOIN purchases t2
ON t1.address_id = t2.address_id AND t1.purchased_at < t2.purchased_at
WHERE t2.purchased_at IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.purchased_at DESC
```

And most likely a faster approach:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM purchases t1
JOIN (
    SELECT address_id, max(purchased_at) max_purchased_at
    FROM purchases
    GROUP BY address_id
) t2
ON t1.address_id = t2.address_id AND t1.purchased_at = t2.max_purchased_at
ORDER BY t1.purchased_at DESC
```

Comment: In very few words: The only purchased_at value that has no bigger value is the max, now, return only those rows :) For further reading take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: How is the efficiency of this query approach?

Comment: qq regarding your 1st approach: What if the two last purchases were made at the same time? Looks like I'm getting two rows for the same address.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Does not cater for duplicate purchased_at.

Comment: @barnacle.m That is not really for you to decide. You don't know if for the OP, seeing all the matching column IDs is relevant or not. The obvious question would be: what ID would you show if more than one row matches? You will have to select one and discard the rest. And maybe, the query was used to analyze information that would DELETE ALL the matching rows. So hiding information unilaterally without understanding the business case is not the right way to go. Rather than downvoting, probably you should ask the OP

Comment: No, he's looking for a single record returned according to the question. If the purchased_at is identical to another record, then this solution does _not_ in fact solve it, and anybody else such as myself who came here looking for a solution to the same issue, will usually look at the accepted answer as the "ideal" method, but in this case it is simply incorrect.

Comment: @bernacle.m Nowhere in the question states the answer should return a "single record" or that the OP is a "he". You should read the question carefully rather than skipping to the selected answer and assuming your issue matches the OP's one. Not to mention *purchased_at* could be part of a unique key, but you don't know that either.

Answer (score 14):

Your ORDER BY is used by [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) for picking which row for each distinct address_id to produce.  If you then want to order the resulting records, make the DISTINCT ON a subselect and order its results:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) purchases.address_id, purchases.*
  FROM "purchases"
  WHERE "purchases"."product_id" = 2
  ORDER BY purchases.address_id ASC, purchases.purchased_at DESC
) distinct_addrs
order by distinct_addrs.purchased_at DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I think that join will be better than subquery, especially when you want to use this inside rails (not just query execute, but construct it in some rails way)

Comment: Best answer, helped me to understand :)

Comment: this is actually the only good working answer. also you can just use `SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id)  *` in the second select row

Comment: If I want to limit this for the purposes of paginating on the `purchased_at` this ends up being a problem, the limit has to be applied on the outside. But this means we are always fetching all the rows before applying a limit.

Answer (score 4):

This query is trickier to rephrase properly than it looks.

The [currently accepted, join-based answer](/a/9796161/9410) doesn’t correctly handle the case where two candidate rows have the same given `purchased_at` value: it will return both rows.

You can get the right behaviour this way:

```
SELECT * FROM purchases AS given
WHERE product_id = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM purchases AS other
    WHERE given.address_id = other.address_id
    AND (given.purchased_at < other.purchased_at OR given.id < other.id)
)
ORDER BY purchased_at DESC
```

Note how it has a fallback of comparing `id` values to disambiguate the case in which the `purchased_at` values match. This ensures that the condition can only ever be true for a single row among those that have the same `address_id` value.

The original query using `DISTINCT ON` handles this case automatically!

Also note the way that you are forced to encode the fact that you want “the latest for each `address_id`” twice, both in the `given.purchased_at < other.purchased_at` condition and the `ORDER BY purchased_at DESC` clause, and you have to make sure they match. I had to spend a few extra minutes to convince myself that this query is really positively correct.

It’s much easier to write this query correctly and understandbly by using `DISTINCT ON` together with an outer subquery, as suggested by [dbenhur](/users/1074296).

Answer (score -1):

Try this !

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (address_id) *
FROM   purchases
WHERE  product_id = 2
ORDER  BY address_id, purchased_at DESC
```