# How do I take a DISTINCT ON subquery that is ordered by a separate column, and make it fast?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

(AKA - With a query and data very similar to question "[Selecting rows ordered by some column and distinct on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796078/selecting-rows-ordered-by-some-column-and-distinct-on-another)", how can I get it to run fast). Postgres 11.

I have table `prediction` with `(article_id, prediction_date, predicted_as, article_published_date)` that represents the output from a classifier over a set of articles.

New articles are frequently added to a separate table (Represented by the FK `article_id`), and new predictions are added as we tune our classifier.

Sample data:

```
| id      | article_id |  predicted_as | prediction_date | article_published_date
| 1009381 | 362718     |  negative     | 2018-07-27      | 2018-06-26
| 1009382 | 362718     |  positive     | 2018-08-12      | 2018-06-26
| 1009383 | 362719     |  positive     | 2018-08-13      | 2010-09-22
| 1009384 | 362719     |  positive     | 2018-09-28      | 2010-09-22
| 1009385 | 362719     |  negative     | 2018-10-01      | 2010-09-22
```

Create table script:

```
create table prediction
(
    id serial not null
        constraint prediction_pkey
            primary key,
    article_id integer not null
        constraint prediction_article_id_fkey
            references article,
    predicted_as classifiedas not null,
    prediction_date date not null,
    article_published_date date not null
);

create index prediction_article_id_prediction_date_idx
    on prediction (article_id asc, prediction_date desc);
```

We frequently want to view the most recent classification for each article. In order to do so we use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (article_id) article_id, id, article_published_date
FROM prediction
ORDER BY article_id, prediction_date desc
```

which returns something like:

```
| id     | article_id |  predicted_as | prediction_date | article_published_date
| 120950 | 1          | negative      | 2018-06-29      | 2018-03-25
| 120951 | 2          | negative      | 2018-06-29      | 2018-03-19
```

With an index on `(article_id, prediciton_date desc)`, this query runs very quickly (~15ms). This is the explain plan:

```
Unique  (cost=0.56..775374.53 rows=1058394 width=20)
  ->  Index Scan using prediction_article_id_prediction_date_id_idx on prediction  (cost=0.56..756071.98 rows=7721023 width=20)
```

So far so good.

The problem occurs when I want to sort this result by the article_published_field. E.g:

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
select *
  from (
         select distinct on (article_id) article_id, id, article_published_date
         from prediction
         order by article_id, prediction_date desc
       ) most_recent_predictions
  order by article_published_date desc
  limit 3;
```

This works, but the query takes ~3-4 seconds to run, making it too slow to use directly to respond to a web request.

Here is the explain plan:

```
Limit  (cost=558262.52..558262.53 rows=3 width=12) (actual time=4748.977..4748.979 rows=3 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=7621849 read=9051
  ->  Sort  (cost=558262.52..560851.50 rows=1035593 width=12) (actual time=4748.975..4748.976 rows=3 loops=1)
        Sort Key: most_recent_predictions.article_published_date DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=7621849 read=9051
        ->  Subquery Scan on most_recent_predictions  (cost=0.43..544877.67 rows=1035593 width=12) (actual time=0.092..4508.464 rows=1670807 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=7621849 read=9051
              ->  Result  (cost=0.43..534521.74 rows=1035593 width=16) (actual time=0.092..4312.916 rows=1670807 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=7621849 read=9051
                    ->  Unique  (cost=0.43..534521.74 rows=1035593 width=16) (actual time=0.090..4056.644 rows=1670807 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=7621849 read=9051
                          ->  Index Scan using prediction_article_id_prediction_date_idx on prediction  (cost=0.43..515295.09 rows=7690662 width=16) (actual time=0.089..3248.250 rows=7690662 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=7621849 read=9051
Planning Time: 0.130 ms
Execution Time: 4749.007 ms
```

Is there any way to make this query run more quickly, or will I have to resort to refreshing a materialized view or setting up a trigger system to get this data quickly?

For reference:

- the `prediction` table has 7.7M rows
- there are 1.7M distinct `article_id`s in the `prediction` table
- there is an index on `(article_id, prediciton_date desc)` as well as one on `article_published_date desc`
- `VACUUM ANALYSE` has been run

Comment: About `limit 3`: is that for testing, or do you actually just want the top 3? Your explanation is not in sync with the query. Also, `EXPLAIN` is good, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` is *much* better to help us understand. And I assume there is also a table `article` holding all relevant (unique) articles? (You mentioned an FK ...)

Comment: You provided good information, better than most. Still (as *always*), actual `CREATE TABLE` scripts would be more helpful. For starters, it matters whether columns are defined `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Hi @ErwinBrandstetter - I've updated the `explain` with `(ANALYZE, BUFFERS` and added the create table script.

Comment: There is a separate article table that is accessed through the FK, but it is not actually accessed for this query. The `article_id` on the table is sufficient.

Comment: The most important question was my first, about `LIMIT 3`?

Comment: We actually need the top ~3-10. 3 would suffice. The updated query + explain reflects a limit of 3

Comment: OK, my idea should work for any trivially small `LIMIT`. (But not for large parts of the result.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if you can make this work:

```
select article_id, id, article_published_date
from prediction p
where p.prediction_date = (select max(p2.prediction_date)
                           from prediction p2
                           where p2.article_id = p.article_id
                          )
order by article_published_date desc;
```

Then use these two indexes:

- `(article_published_date desc, prediction_date, article_id, id)`
- `(article_id, prediction_date desc)`.

Comment: Hey Gordon - this appears to do the job! Thanks

Comment: This does not remove duplicates on `(article_published_date, prediction_date)` like the original does.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you *could try* is to use window function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)` instead of `DISTINCT ON()` (which implies constraints on the `ORDER BY` clause). This method is functionaly equivalent to your second query, and *might* be able to take advantage of exising indexes:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        article_id, 
        id, 
        article_published_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY article_id ORDER BY prediction_date DESC) rn
    FROM prediction 
) x WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY article_published_date DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2HcQdF9nfgT2ojnerZt54m/1)**.

Comment: Hey @GMB - the above query is about 3x slower than the distinct on. The `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` is up here: https://pastebin.com/b6fZy5nP

Comment: @mjames: thanks for the intersting feedback. I guess that somehow Postgres is able to optimize `DISTINCT ON()` better than the standard `ROW_NUMBER()`, which is not that suprizing after all, since the former is a bit limited compared to the latter (see my answer).

Comment: @mjames: I can see that you accepted an answer, but did not upvote any, while you have enough rep for that. Wasn't any of these answers useful to you?

Comment: Thanks @GMB - didn't realize that that was proper etiquette. All of the answers were well thought out - is the best practice to upvote each of them, or just the solution?

Answer (score 2):

While you just want a trivially small number of result rows (`LIMIT 3` in your example), and if there is any positive correlation between `article_published_date` and `prediction_date`, this query should be **radically** faster as it only has to scan few tuples from the top of the added index (and recheck with the 2nd index):

Have these two **indexes**:

```
CREATE INDEX ON prediction (article_published_date DESC, prediction_date DESC, article_id DESC);

CREATE INDEX ON prediction (article_id, prediction_date DESC);
```

**Recursive Query:**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT p.article_published_date, p.article_id, p.prediction_date, ARRAY[p.article_id] AS a_ids
   FROM   prediction p
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (  -- no later row for same article
      SELECT FROM prediction
      WHERE  article_id = p.article_id
      AND    prediction_date > p.prediction_date
      )
   ORDER  BY p.article_published_date DESC, p.prediction_date DESC, p.article_id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.article_published_date, p.article_id, p.prediction_date, a_ids || p.article_id
   FROM   cte c, LATERAL (
      SELECT p.article_published_date, p.article_id, p.prediction_date
      FROM   prediction p
      WHERE (p.article_published_date, p.prediction_date, p.article_id)
          < (c.article_published_date, c.prediction_date, c.article_id)
      AND    p.article_id <> ALL(a_ids)   -- different article
      AND    NOT EXISTS (                 -- no later row for same article
         SELECT FROM prediction
         WHERE  article_id = p.article_id
         AND    prediction_date > p.prediction_date
         )
      ORDER  BY p.article_published_date DESC, p.prediction_date DESC, p.article_id DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) p
   )
SELECT article_published_date, article_id, prediction_date
FROM   cte
LIMIT  3;
```

Here is a **plpgsql solution** doing the same, probably slightly faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_top_n_predictions(_n int = 3)
  RETURNS TABLE (_article_published_date date, _article_id int, _prediction_date date) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   a_ids int[];
BEGIN
   FOR _article_published_date, _article_id, _prediction_date IN
      SELECT article_published_date, article_id, prediction_date
      FROM   prediction
      ORDER  BY article_published_date DESC, prediction_date DESC, article_id DESC
   LOOP
      IF _article_id = ANY(a_ids)
      OR EXISTS (SELECT FROM prediction p
                 WHERE  p.article_id = _article_id
                 AND    p.prediction_date > _prediction_date) THEN
         -- do nothing         
      ELSE
         RETURN NEXT;
         a_ids := a_ids || _article_id;
         EXIT WHEN cardinality(a_ids) >= _n;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_top_n_predictions();
```

I'll add explanation if it works for you, since the explanation is more work than the query itself.

---

Apart from that, with more than a few predictions per article, and with an additional table `article`, this query becomes a contender:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   article a
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT p.article_published_date, p.article_id, p.prediction_date
   FROM   prediction p
   WHERE  p.article_id = a.id
   ORDER  BY p.prediction_date DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.article_published_date DESC;
```

But you don't need this if the query above does the job. Gets interesting for a bigger or no `LIMIT`.

Basics:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Can spatial index help a “range - order by - limit” query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18300/3684)

***db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=05df34bf7a879dd4381a2ebb63252742)***, demonstrating all.

Comment: Hi @ErwinBrandstetter - the first query is much slower than my naive approach - it takes 43 seconds to run (vs 4). I added both indices, and analyzed the table. The EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) is up here:
https://pastebin.com/8D5rGQDE

Comment: Ah! The index was wrong. The crucial detail is to have `article_published_date` first. Can you try once more. I am aiming for microseconds, not seconds. Also, how does my second query compare to your original? With just 5 to 6 rows per article, `DISTINCT ON` might still be faster than my second query.

Comment: @mjames: Did you find time to try with the fixed index? Or the plpgsql alternative?