# Get distinct on one column, order by another

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm building a messaging feature for an app, my database table looks like this:

```
messages:
  id
  senderId
  receiverId
  threadId   <-- every message is part of a thread
  createdAt
```

I have a 'Messages' page which has a card for every message thread, but I want it to show the latest message in the card as a preview for each thread. This is the query I've written so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("threadId") * FROM messages ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC;
```

So I'm doing `DISTINCT ON ("threadId")`, but I'm also selecting all the columns because I want all the data, that's why there's a `*` after the `DISTINCT ON` clause. This query worked fine up until this point, but now it's failing on the `ORDER BY` clause. I want to return the message that was created last, but I'm getting an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
> LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("threadId") * FROM messages order by "cr...
> ```

I understand the error I think (the `ORDER BY` column has to match the column that `DISTINCT ON` is being applied to) but I don't know how to get the query to be what I want, which is to be ordered by `createdAt` before it becomes distinct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leading expressions in `ORDER BY` have to agree with expressions in `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("threadId") *
FROM   messages
ORDER  BY "threadId", "createdAt" DESC;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

---

**If** you want to order results in a *different way* (like commented), you'll have to wrap the query in an outer query with a second `ORDER BY`. See:

- [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by/9796104#9796104)

Or similar, depending on your exact situation and requirements. There may be sophistication to get best results. Recent example:

- [How do I take a DISTINCT ON subquery that is ordered by a separate column, and make it fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55202502/939860)

Comment: what happens if i want to do another order by on another column on the final result?

Comment: @duxfox--: I added some more above to address that.