# Aggregate functions are not allowed in FILTER

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.name,
    users.avatar,
    MAX(messages.created_at) max_created_at,
    MAX(messages.body) FILTER (WHERE messages.created_at = MAX(messages.created_at)) last_message,
    CASE WHEN(COUNT(messages.is_read) FILTER (WHERE is_read = false AND messages.from_id != 14) = 0) THEN true ELSE false END is_read,
    COUNT(messages.is_read) FILTER (WHERE is_read = false AND messages.from_id != 14) count_unread
FROM 
    messages 
INNER JOIN 
    users ON messages.from_id = users.id OR messages.to_id = users.id
WHERE 
    (messages.from_id = 14 OR messages.to_id = 14) 
    AND users.id != 14
GROUP BY 
    users.id;
```

But, this query is showing an error

> Aggregate functions are not allowed in FILTER

When I change

```
MAX(messages.body) FILTER (WHERE messages.created_at = MAX(messages.created_at)) last_message
```

to

```
MAX(messages.body) FILTER (HAVING messages.created_at = MAX(messages.created_at)) last_message
```

the query is now showing this error

> Syntax error at or near "HAVING"

How to fix this?

Comment: does it work if you do `FILTER(WHERE messages.created_at = max_created_at)` ?

Comment: it does not work. that's the first error says. @Breezer

Comment: Remember to always disclose table definition and your version of Postgres. Either can make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done with window functions and `DISTINCT ON` in a single instance of `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.id)
       u.id, u.name, u.avatar
     , m.created_at  AS max_created_at
     , m.body        AS last_message
     , bool_and(is_read) FILTER (WHERE m.from_id <> 14)          OVER w AS is_read
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT m.is_read AND m.from_id <> 14) OVER w AS count_unread
FROM   messages m
JOIN   users    u ON u.id IN (m.from_id, m.to_id)
WHERE  14 IN (m.from_id, m.to_id)
AND    u.id <> 14
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY u.id)
ORDER  BY u.id, m.created_at DESC NULLS LAST, m.body DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

Comment: I'm satisfied with this answer. But I also have a question. What if I want to sort the data by max_created_at?

Comment: @BoboBoy: These should cover it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55302068/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796104/939860

Answer (score 0):

I  think you require this:

```
select a.* from(
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.name,
    users.avatar,
    MAX(messages.created_at) max_created_at,
    messages.body   last_message,
    CASE WHEN(COUNT(messages.is_read) FILTER (WHERE is_read = false AND messages.from_id != 14) = 0) THEN true ELSE false END is_read,
    COUNT(messages.is_read) FILTER (WHERE is_read = false AND messages.from_id != 14) count_unread,
        RANK () OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY messages.created_at DESC
    ) message_rank 
FROM 
    messages 
INNER JOIN 
    users ON messages.from_id = users.id OR messages.to_id = users.id
WHERE 
    (messages.from_id = 14 OR messages.to_id = 14) 
    AND users.id != 14
GROUP BY 
    users.id)a
where message_rank=1;
```

Comment: the query is now showing this error `subquery in FROM must have an alias`