# selecting DISTINCT rows that are ordered by something different

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

i have this table `performances`, where there are performances of theatre plays from other table:

```
id | play_id |    when    | other uninteresting meta data
1  |    3    | 2020-04-01 |             ...
2  |    4    | 2020-03-03 |             
3  |    3    | 2020-01-02 |             
4  |    1    | 2020-06-03 |             
5  |    4    | 2020-10-13 |
```

and i would like to select the earliest performance for each distinct play (so each play is represented by a single, earliest, performance), ordered from soonest to latest.

so from the presented data i would like to get this:

```
id | play_id |    when    | other uninteresting meta data
3  |    3    | 2020-01-02 |             ...
2  |    4    | 2020-03-03 |             
4  |    1    | 2020-06-03 |
```

so far, after studying some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796078/selecting-rows-ordered-by-some-column-and-distinct-on-another) i came up with this query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (play_id) *
  FROM performances
  WHERE performances.deleted_at is null
  ORDER BY performances.play_id ASC, performances.when ASC
) distinct_plays
order by distinct_plays.when ASC
```

however, i don't trust it at all, because in the linked threads there were people bickering and telling that each other's answers are wrong; and while i see some problems with the answers in that thread i don't see a problem in this answer yet.

is this a good query for my task? does it not select duplicate rows or is very ineffective?

Comment: is this mysql or postgresql?  please don't tag both without an explanation of why

Comment: Your query does what you want. What happens when you run it?

Comment: @ysth it is postgres but i assume mysql has the same syntax for this

Comment: @GMB it returns a good set on my data, i was just unsure about unforseen scenarios (just like people pointed potential duplicate rows in the 2 previous threads)

Comment: indeed not, mysql does not have "DISTINCT ON"

Comment: ok, i have removed the mysql query. however, i would still like to know about a more generic approach, as i will be implementing this into laravel framework's `Eloquent` model which is trying to use database agnostic queries

Comment: I was among the "bickering people" at the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9795660/939860), because the accepted answer had been incorrect. It got fixed after that. Let me assure you: your current query is 100% correct. Detailed explanation for  `DISTINCT ON` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860). Depending on data distribution, there may be faster solutions. If performance is important, provide details as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). Maybe in a new question.

Comment: @user151496 . . . If you have a question about Postgres, listen to Erwin Brandstetter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does what you want. `distinct on` is usually the right tool in Postgres to solve such greatest-n-per-group problem... alas, it gives no flexibility on the order of rows in the resultset.

It appears that you want a different sort in the result as in `distinct on` - so you need another level of nesting for this. While your code does what you want, I will recommend using `row_number()` instead (which has also the advantage of being supported in many databases, as opposed to vendor-specific `distinct on`):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY play_id ORDER BY p.when asc) rn
    FROM performances p
    WHERE p.deleted_at is null
) p
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY p.when asc
```

You might also want to try a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM performances p
WHERE p.deleted_at IS NULL AND p.when = (
    SELECT MIN(p1.when) FROM performances p1 WHERE p1.play_id = p.play_id
)
ORDER BY p.when
```

For performance with the correlated subquery, consider an index on `(play_id, when)`.

Comment: thank you! i will use your first query, as i would like make my applicatoin database independent. however, i have fixed the order to be ascending to give it the results that i want. but your second query is wrong, as it would return unwanted rows with the same `play_ids` in case they have the same `when` value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_value` for that:

```
select first_value(id) over(w), play_id, first_value(when) over(w) -- the rest of the columns analogously
from performances
group by play_id
window w as (partition by play_id order by when)
```

Comment: that doesn't get the "other uninteresting meta data" columns, which I believe they want (and want to be from the row with the least when)

Comment: @ysth `first_value` needs to be used on every column analogously, thanks for the comment