# Retrieve aggregates for arbitrary time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

This is the query I have so far, to create daily bars:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('hour',t) AS date,
min(price) OVER w,
max(price) OVER w,
first_value(price) OVER w,
last_value(price) OVER w
FROM ticker
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY date_trunc('hour',t));
```

Changing 'hour' to 'min' or 'day' would give me the bars corresponding to these units.

However, what if I want 5 min or 15 min bars? `date_trunc()` doesn't support these and I'm looking for a nice elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

#### Postgres 14 or newer:

Postgres 14 added the function [**`date_bin()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN).
Now this works for *any* interval. Example with 15 minutes:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       date_bin('15 min', t, timestamp '2012-07-18 00:00') AS bin
     , min(price)        OVER w  AS min_prize
     , max(price)        OVER w  AS max_prize
     , price                     AS first_price
     , last_value(price) OVER w  AS last_price
FROM   ticker
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY t)
ORDER  BY 1, t;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eaEA6DGb)

To include empty bins (no matching rows), you still need to `LEFT JOIN` to a grid like below.

#### Postgres 13 or older

For any number of minutes. Example with 15 minutes:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
       date_trunc('hour', t) AS hour
     , floor(EXTRACT(minute FROM t) / 15) AS quarter
     , min(price) OVER w AS min_prize
     , max(price) OVER w AS max_prize
     , price AS first_price
     , last_value(price) OVER w AS last_price
FROM   ticker
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY 1, 2 ORDER BY t)
ORDER  BY 1, 2, t;
```

---

A more **generic solution** for any regular time intervals, across any period of time, and including empty bins (no matching rows):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (grid.bin)
       grid.bin
     , min(price)        OVER w  AS min_prize
     , max(price)        OVER w  AS max_prize
     , price                     AS first_prize
     , last_value(price) OVER w  AS last_prize
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2012-07-18 00:00'  -- your time range here
                     , timestamp '2012-07-18 01:15'
                     , interval  '5 min') grid(bin)
LEFT   JOIN ticker t ON t.t >= grid.bin                     -- use JOIN to exclude empty intervals
                    AND t.t <  grid.bin + interval '5 min'  -- don't use BETWEEN
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY grid.bin ORDER BY t)
ORDER  BY grid.bin, t.t;
```

Related:

- [Best way to count rows by arbitrary time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576794/best-way-to-count-records-by-arbitrary-time-intervals-in-railspostgres/15577413#15577413)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)