# Django order_by() filter with distinct()

Tags: django, django-models, django-aggregation, django-filters

How can I make an `order_by` like this ....

```
p = Product.objects.filter(vendornumber='403516006')\
                   .order_by('-created').distinct('vendor__name')
```

The problem is that I have multiple vendors with the same name, and I only want the latest product by the vendor ..

Hope it makes sense?

I got this DB error:

> SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
>   LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("search_vendor"."name")
>   "search_product"...

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Based on your error message and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-without-ordering), it seems to me this would fix it:

```
p = Product.objects.filter(vendornumber='403516006')\
               .order_by('vendor__name', '-created').distinct('vendor__name')
```

That is, it seems that the `DISTINCT ON` expression(s) must match the leftmost `ORDER BY` expression(s). So by making the column you use in `distinct` as the first column in the `order_by`, I think it should work.

Comment: But with this method it will first order by vendor name and only use "created" as a secondary ordering. Which means the order by "created" will be incorrect.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: @Ness What you say is true. But not necessarily relevant. It seems the OP was not interested in ordering by `created`. He used `created` not for the purpose of ordering the final result, but for getting the correct record per vendor. It seems the ordering of the vendors was not important in the use case of the OP. In fact we don't know the true intended ordering, it's essentially unspecified by OP.

Comment: Thank you, really not an obvious thing.

Comment: what if I want to order by something else but have distinct values in another column?

Comment: Thank you! You made my day.

Answer (score 31):

Just matching leftmost order_by() arg and distinct() did not work for me, producing the same error (Django 1.8.7 bug or a feature)?

```
qs.order_by('project').distinct('project')
```

however it worked when I changed to:

```
qs.order_by('project__id').distinct('project')
```

and I do not even have multiple order_by args.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me running Django 2.0.2 and PostgreSQL 10.1. I tried the other suggestions involving matching the order of arguments for `order_by` and `distinct` and those did not solve the issue.

Comment: Same issue here, not sure why _id was needed

Comment: I also had success with adding __id to the order_by() but not the distinct()

Comment: @dowjones123 The reason may be the default ordering defined on the related model (Project in this answer). The documentation [mentions this case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) in the last Note in 'distinct()' description.

Comment: In the original question `.order_by('-created')` is likely a datetime-like field. This answer doesn't help to sort by such a field, then get distinct. Clearly useful for other scenarios, but not for helpful for the specific question asked.

Answer (score 29):

In case you are hoping to use a separate field for distinct and order by another field you can use the below code

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

Model.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Subquery(
       Model.objects.all().distinct('foo').values('pk')
    )
).order_by('bar')
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly with prefetch related as far as I can tell...

Comment: The other answers didn't work for me because I needed to perform ordering on other fields at a later time from that same queryset. This one worked.

Comment: This worked for me - but needed order_by
... Model.objects.all().order_by('foo').distinct('foo').values('pk') ...

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue but then with related fields. With just adding the related field in `distinct()`, I didn't get the right results.

I wanted to sort by `room__name` keeping the `person` (linked to `residency` ) unique. Repeating the related field as per the below fixed my issue:

```
.order_by('room__name', 'residency__person', ).distinct('room__name', 'residency__person')
```

See also these related posts:

- [ProgrammingError: when using order_by and distinct together in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865235/programmingerror-when-using-order-by-and-distinct-together-in-django)
- [django distinct and order_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621879/django-distinct-and-order-by)
- [Postgresql DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by)