# django distinct and order_by

Tags: django, django-queryset

`Foo.objects.all().distinct('foo')` won't remove duplicates

`Foo.objects.all().order_by().distinct('foo')` does remove them.

I have Meta.ordering = ('-field1', '-field2)

Does `Foo.objects.all().order_by().distinct('foo')` respects the Meta.ordering?
i.e. I want distinct values ordered by Meta.ordering and not sure how to do it.

Django Documentation is confusing and don't address how `order_by()` without any argument works.

I'm using postgresql 9.3 btw.

```
In [28]: BestMomsdiaryThread.objects.all().values_list('momsdiary_thread__id', flat=True)
Out[28]: [3390, 5877, 5884, 6573, 5880, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, 6576, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']

In [29]: BestMomsdiaryThread.objects.not_deleted().order_by().distinct('momsdiary_thread').values_list('momsdiary_thread__id', flat=True)
Out[29]: [3390, 5877, 5880, 5884]

In [30]: BestMomsdiaryThread.objects.not_deleted().values_list('momsdiary_thread__id', flat=True)
Out[30]: [3390, 5877, 5884, 5880, 5877, 5880, 5884, 3390]


In [32]: BestMomsdiaryThread.objects.not_deleted().order_by('momsdiary_thread').distinct('momsdiary_thread').values_list('momsdiary_thread__id', flat=True)

ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("momsplanner_bestmomsdiarythread"."momsd...


                      ^
```

Comment: Only in postgress: [" For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Comment: @danihp: yes, but your have to supply `order_by()` without no arguments, and I'm not sure if that will respect Meta.ordering.

Comment: `order_by()` with out parameters *don't* respect Meta ordering. It is intended to clear inherit ordered from model meta in order to improve performance where sort is not needed (remember than order may include referenced fields and joins ). All is in docs.

Comment: @danihp: thanks for help. it was because I can't use the object itself in order_by. I had to use order_by('momsdiary_thread_id') instead of ('momsdiary_thread'). I can accept if you post an answer

Answer (score 8):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

> If you don’t want any ordering to be applied to a query, not even the default ordering, call order_by() with no parameters.