# ProgrammingError: when using order_by and distinct together in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, sql-order-by, distinct

I have a model like below

```
class ProductScore(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    scale = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

As of now i am using the below query to filter out the duplicates from the above model

```
scores = ProductScore.objects.filter(client=request.user).distinct('scale')
```

By the above query it was returning the unique results but are old(created date was very old), i mean for example if the above table `ProductScore` has 10 duplicate records in which 5 of them are created yesterday and 5 of them are created today, the above query is returning 5 unique records which are created yesterday.

But i want the records which are created mostly recently(i.e., today) and unique so i tried like below

```
scores = ProductScore.objects.filter(client=request.user).order_by('created').distinct('scale')
```

which was not working and throwing some `programming error exception`

```
*** ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("product_productscore"."scale...
                            ^
```

So how can i get the most recently created unique records form the above table ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PostgreSQL is asking you to do this:

```
ProductScore.objects.filter(client=request.user).order_by('scale', '-created').distinct('scale')
```

...ordering by `-created` will give you the most recent of each duplicate, though your overall query results will be ordered by `scale` field

Comment: Thanks that worked !!!! but when adjusted the order_by part with `order_by('sub_scale', '-created')` instead of `order_by(('scale', '-created'))`

Comment: ah yes my mistake, shouldn't pass a tuple to the `order_by`... updated