# python Django ORM group and order a queryset

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

In my django project i have to implement a groupped query with ORM and order results for a specific field.
I do this:

```
a = tt.objects.filter(thread_status = 'DEAD').select_related().distinct('thread_stag').order_by('-id')[0:20]
```

but the response is an error:

> ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

How can i do distinct and order_by in same query on different columns?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

can you try this one? [references from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582966/django-order-by-filter-with-distinct)

```
a = tt.objects.filter(thread_status = 'DEAD').select_related()\
              .distinct('thread_stag').order_by('thread_stag', '-id')[0:20]
```

or

```
a = tt.objects.filter(thread_status = 'DEAD').select_related()\
              .order_by('thread_stag', '-id').distinct('thread_stag')[0:20]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your query system doesn't return any error but the results are not ordered

Comment: because the first order is for thread_stag, i need to order results just for id. Thanks in advance