# Django query gives "SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions" error even specified the same order

Tags: django

```
VirtualMachine.objects.order_by('pool__customer').distinct('pool__customer')
```

[image]

Been thru this [ticket already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582966/django-order-by-filter-with-distinct)

also tried asking ChatGPT (lol), the answer doesn't have `.all()` but gave the same error, wouldn't think it made a difference anyway cos `.order_by('pool__customer')` should overwrite it already
[image]

Comment: Can you explain *what* you want to do (not *how* you want to do it) and share the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks I didn't know going thru FK tables would have implications thought that if I only specify the same field in order_by would work. But I got my answer now.

Comment: It might help to fix the problem in another way. Here for each customer you seem to return *a* virtual machine (although what is not specified and thus can differ between two queries).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah that would work as well haha but that is a N+1 problem

Comment: not with `Customer.objects.prefetch_related('virtualmachine_set')` or something similar, then it will make one query for the `Customer`s, and a second for all virtual machines for these customers in a single query.

Comment: yeah my problem is I need to filter the virtualmachine.updated_at in a range

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you want, for each `Customer`, the `VirtualMachine`s that are in a certain timerange.

You can do this with a [**`Prefetch`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Customer.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'virtualmachine_set',
        VirtualMachine.objects.filter(
            datetime_field__range=('2022-11-25', '2023-3-25')
        ),
    )
)
```

This will fetch only `VirtualMachine`s where a field (here `datetime_field` is within a certain range).

Answer (score 0):

ah... once I printed the raw query then I realised it generated different order by

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("customerpool"."customer_id")
"virtualmachine"."id",
"virtualmachine"."name",
"virtualmachine"."uuid",
...
FROM   "truebill_virtualmachine"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "customerpool"
                    ON ( "virtualmachine"."pool_id" =
                         "customerpool"."pool" )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "customer"
                    ON ( "customerpool"."customer_id" =
                         "customer"."code" )
ORDER  BY "customer"."code" ASC
```

so once I changed the query to this and it worked.

```
VirtualMachine.objects.distinct('pool__customer').order_by('pool__customer_id')
```

Comment: Was there an `ordering = ...` on the model?

Comment: yeah the `Customer` model also has default ordering, but i didn't realise it was talking about this model

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get distinct value from `pool__customer` field in VirtualMachine model, you can use

```
VirtualMachine.objects.values_list('pool__customer', flat=True).distinct()
```

You can read more in [Django values_list vs values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205793/django-values-list-vs-values)