# Django Grab Only First of Each Primary Key in Query

Tags: python, django

I have a model as below.  I want to query it and fetch only the first (newest) row of each `tagid`.

So I do something like this

```py
tag_ids = [list of tagid]
q = Q(tagid__in=tag_ids, dataintegirty=192)
items = get_model().objects.filter(q).order_by('-t_stamp')
```

That query works, but it returns several hundred thousand rows that I don't need.  I only need the first of each `tagid`.

How can I achieve that kind of query in Django?

```py
class TagDataBase(BaseModel):
    tagid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    intvalue = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    floatvalue = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    stringvalue = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    datevalue = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    dataintegrity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    t_stamp = TimestampField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        abstract = True
        db_table = 'sqlt_data_1_2023_02'
        unique_together = (('tagid', 't_stamp'),)
```

It's abstract because the db_table changes, and I fetch the model class using a `get_model()` method.

Note:

- The model is not managed by Django and thus the fields cannot be changed.
- DB is MariaDB 10.9

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: You need to use [distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) (or alternative, depending on database) with `ORDER BY`. [This might answer your question on how to use those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582966/django-order-by-filter-with-distinct)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem mariadb 10.9

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code:
First, the filter() function accepts only keyword [arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters), so the `q` in `get_model().objects.filter(q).order_by('-t_stamp')` isn't doing all that much.
Second, it doesn't make a lot of sense to

> fetch only the first, newest row of each tagid

, since tagid is a primary key and therefore unique.
Third, is there a reason why your model isn't inheriting from models.Model instead of BaseModel?

I would rewrite your model as:

```
class TagDataBase(models.Model):
    tagid = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, every model has an unique id and a tagid.
To get the newest row of a given tagid, you should run: `item = get_model().objects.filter(tagid=var).order_by('-t_stamp')[0]`

Comment: I do not have the option to rewrite the model.  The database isn't managed by Django. And I forgot to mention that `q` being passed into the filter is a Django `Q` object. Also `tagid` can appear multiple times in the table.  The only requirement is that it and `t_stamp` are unique together.  And I'm trying to fetch related to multiple tags at once.  I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch only the first (newest) row of each **tagid** in your Django query, you can use the **distinct()** method along with the **values()** method.

Get the newest (maximum) t_stamp for each tagid`get_model().objects.filter(q).values('tagid').annotate(max_t_stamp=Max('t_stamp'))` then Fetch the first (newest) row for each tagid `get_model().objects.filter(q, t_stamp__in=subquery.values('max_t_stamp')).order_by('tagid')`

```
tag_ids = [list of tagid]
q = Q(tagid__in=tag_ids, dataintegirty=192)

subquery = get_model().objects.filter(q).values('tagid').annotate(max_t_stamp=Max('t_stamp'))

items = get_model().objects.filter(q, t_stamp__in=subquery.values('max_t_stamp')).order_by('tagid')
```