# Custom aggregate function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to write an aggregate function in PostgreSQL that will calculate a delta value, by substracting the initial (last value in the column) from the current(first value in column) ?
It would apply on a structure like this

```
rankings (userId, rank, timestamp)
```

And could be used like

```
SELECT userId, custum_agg(rank) OVER w 
FROM rankings
WINDOWS w AS (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY timstamp desc)
```

returning for an userId the rank of the newest entry (by timestamp) - rank of the oldest entry (by timestamp)

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's a window, not an aggregate, but yes. As far as I know you must currently write window functions in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the rank of the newest entry (by timestamp) - rank of the oldest entry (by timestamp)

There are many ways to achieve this with existing functions.
You can use the existing [window functions `first_value()` and `last_value()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html), combined with `DISTINCT` or `DISTINCT ON` to get it without joins and subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid)
       userid
     , last_value(rank) OVER w  
     - first_value(rank) OVER w AS rank_delta
FROM   rankings
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY ts
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
             AND  UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING);
```

Note the custom [frames for the window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)!

Or you can use basic aggregate functions in a subquery and JOIN:

```
SELECT userid, r2.rank - r1.rank AS rank_delta
FROM  (
  SELECT userid
       , min(ts) AS first_ts
       , max(ts) AS last_ts
   FROM  rankings
   GROUP BY 1
   ) sub
JOIN   rankings r1 USING (userid)
JOIN   rankings r2 USING (userid)
WHERE  r1.ts = first_ts
AND    r2.ts = last_ts;
```

Assuming unique `(userid, rank)`, or your requirements would be ambiguous.

[**SQL Fiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/61109/7)

#### Shichinin no samurai

<sup>... [a.k.a. "7 Samurai"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047478/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2)</sup>
Per request in the comments, the same for only the **last seven rows per userid** (or as many as can be found, if there are fewer):

Again, one of many possible ways. But I believe this to be one of the shortest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid)
       userid
     , first_value(rank) OVER w  
     - last_value(rank)  OVER w AS rank_delta
FROM   rankings
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY ts DESC
             ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 7 FOLLOWING)
ORDER  BY userid, ts DESC;
```

Note the reversed sort order. The first row is the "newest" entry. I span a frame of (max.) 7 rows and pick only the results for the newest entry with `DISTINCT ON`.

[**SQL Fiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a32b/5)

Comment: Thanks Erwin! I tried to further adapt your first solution, using windows, to not using all rankings but only the newest 7 let's say. I did that by modifying to ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING, but somehow i still get all rows, not just top 7 (ordered by timestamp). Any idea why?

Comment: @maephisto: If you adapt the frame, you get varying result per `userid`. My solution builds on identical results per `userid`. Are the "newest 7" supposed to be relative to each row or absolute for the complete table?

Comment: It should be newest 7 entries for a userId. Only them should be taken into consideration, everything else older than the 7th chronological entry has no value

Comment: @maephisto: Do all of them have 7 or more, or can there be fewer?

Comment: It should be possible to have fewer than 7

Comment: @maephisto: I added a solution for just 7. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JOIN and [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in Postgres. The `GRP` query give you the last `rank` values for each `userID` so just join it with `rankings` on `user_id` and substract values.

```
SELECT rankings.userId, 
       rankings.rank-GRP.rank as delta,
       rankings.timestamp
FROM rankings
JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (userId)  userId, rank, timestamp
    FROM rankings
    ORDER BY userId, timestamp DESC
) as GRP ON rankings.userId=GRP.userId
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2e297/5)</kbd>