# Getting Error while ordering a list in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to order a queryset in the view. I get the following Error Message. Kindly help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

**models.py**

```
class Op(models.Model):
    operator = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=False)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Process, null=False)
```

**views.py**

```
op = Op.objects.all().distinct('operator').order_by('operator__employeename')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgresql DISTINCT ON without ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-without-ordering)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this in the **views.py**:

```
op = Op.objects.all().distinct('operator').order_by('operator', 'operator__employeename')
```

Comment: error has vanished but ordering the list is missed.

Comment: You may need have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-without-ordering.