# Rails, PG: Query returns one record per distinct attribute value, sorts by association attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1

I have not been having luck writing a Rails query that returns what I'm looking for. Suggested, posted solutions do not allow me to sort by a different attribute than I am selecting for DISTINCT.

In my situation: each user can purchase multiple order items. There can even be multiple purchases of the same trip, on the same date (say they want to add a friend). I want to return only one OrderItem record for each unique :trip_date_id, then sort by :start_date on that id.

**Model Structure**

```
OrderItem

  # id            :integer
  # trip_id       :integer
  # trip_date_id  :integer
  # buyer_id      :integer

  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :trip_date
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :buyer_id

TripDate

  # id            :integer
  # start_date    :datetime

  has_one     :order_item
  belongs_to  :trip

Trip

  # id            :integer
  # descr         :text

  has_many    :trip_dates
  has_many    :order_items

User
  # id            :integer

  has_many :order_items, :class_name => 'OrderItem', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
```

**Query Attempts**

```
User.rb

*does not return unique trip_date_ids >
        self.order_items.joins(:trip_date).where(buyer_id: self.id).select("DISTINCT(order_items.trip_date_id), trip_dates.start_date, order_items.*").order("order_items.trip_date_id").order("trip_dates.start_date ASC")


*some postings have suggested this >
    self.order_items.joins(:trip_date).where(buyer_id: self.id).order("order_items.trip_date_id ASC, trip_dates.start_date ASC").select("DISTINCT ON(trip_date_id) order_items.trip_date_id, order_items. *")
```

*however, this last query does not sort by trip_date.start_date*. I want to sort first by trip_date.start_date, but select distinct by trip_date_id. Because Postgres wants the first order_by item to match the first DISTINCT item, I can't seem to do both. Does anyone have a solution to this without resorting to .each loops?

Comment: Why can't `trip` and `trip_date` be folded into a single model?

Comment: Multiple trip dates per trip.

Comment: Clarified relationships in code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to use `DISTINCT ON` as the only db-level code, and then use `sort_by`:

```
self.order_items.where(buyer_id: self.id).select("DISTINCT ON (trip_date_id) *").sort_by{|oi| oi.start_date }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Postgres docs:

> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.

Try passing `trip_dates.id` as the leftmost expression in the `.order` part of your query.  See also this StackOverflow question:

[Postgres DISTINCT ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-without-ordering)

Comment: I've done this now, and reviewed that question (along with its improved version) and come up with the new query (in my question), but I can't seem to both order by trip_date.start_date and select distinct by order_item.trip_date_id. Looks like the OP in your linked question had the same issue. Thoughts?