# How to select records with minimum price per group

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'd like to select each pair of two columns in a database, but only select the entry with the lowest price. As a result, I want to output the `id` and the `price` column.

But it does not work:

My table:

```
id | category | type | name | price
1;"car";"pkw";"honda";1000.00
2;"car";"pkw";"bmw";2000.00
```

SQL:

```
select min(price) price, id
from cartable
group by category, type
```

Result:
`Column "cartable.id" must be present in GROUP-BY clause or used in an aggregate function.`

Comment: add  **cartable.id** into the end of your group by. It's one of those weird things that sql doesn't like

Comment: Well but I don't want to group by the ID!

Comment: @jbutler483 I wouldn't call this weird, but sensible. In fact, I consider it brain-dead that MySQL doesn't require this.

Comment: If you aren't going to group by the ID then why is it in the select list?

Comment: @membersound So you want the lowest price plus the ID belonging to it? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Because I want to get the ID as result, but I dont want to group it! At the end there might even be more columns that I would like to include into the result set.

Comment: You are not aggregating price or id (min, max sum etc..) and you are not grouping by them because they are not in your group by clause - therefore SQL does know what to do with them.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the entry with the lowest price, then calculate the lowest price and join the information back in:

```
select ct.*
from cartable ct join
     (select category, type, min(price) as price
      from cartable
      group by category, type
     ) ctp
     on ct.category = ctp.category and ct.type = ctp.type and ct.price = ctp.price;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  cartable ct 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * 
           FROM  cartable 
           WHERE ct.type = type and ct.category = categoery and ct.price < price)
```

For speed caparison can you try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (type, category), id, price
FROM cartable
ORDER BY price DESC
```

Comment: actually this also works, but in my test has very bad costs/performance in lange datasets.

Comment: it does in postgresql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you can't do much else than resolve to use [Select - Over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select price, id
from(
    select price, id, [rnk] = ROW_NUMBER() over( partition by category, type order by price)
    from cartable
) as a
where [rnk]=1
```

**Create index appropriately** and performance are good.

In your example something like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [foo]
ON [dbo].[cartable] ([category],[type])
INCLUDE ([price])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, price
from  cartable C
inner join
(
select min(price) as price , category, type
from cartable
group by category, type
)T
on T.category = C.category
and T.type = C.type
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try:

```
select id, price from cartable 
where price = (select min(price) from cartable);
```