# Remove column duplicates with union join postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I want to hide duplicate columns in my postgresql select statement. 
Here is the sql code:

```
SELECT name, amount, cpu, id 
FROM computersystem, stock 
WHERE cpu=id 
UNION 
SELECT name, amount, ram, id 
FROM computersystem, stock 
WHERE ram=id 
ORDER BY name, amount
```

And the current output:

```
Name:AMD Ultimate Overkill amount:2
Name:AMD Ultimate Overkill amount:10
Name:CPU Heavy, Low Graphics amount:2
Name:CPU Heavy, Low Graphics amount:10
Name:Graphics Heavy, Low CPU amount:8
Name:Graphics Heavy, Low CPU amount:10
```

What I need to get is only 1 of each name

```
Name:AMD Ultimate Overkill amount:2
Name:CPU Heavy, Low Graphics amount:2
Name:Graphics Heavy, Low CPU amount:8
```

Is there a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

[`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795768/5316326) might solve your issue.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
        name,
        amount,
        cpu,
        id
 FROM computersystem, stock 
 WHERE cpu=id 
 UNION SELECT name, amount, ram, id FROM computersystem, stock 
 WHERE ram=id
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY name, amount
```

Find the official documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).