# Django Query, Distinct and Order_By combination not working

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

There are similar questions here but I haven't been able to find one that helps me.

I have two models, Chat and Post

there are multiple Chats, and each chat has multiple posts attached to it.
I'm trying to get the latest post for each chat.

`Post.objects.order_by('-id').distinct('Chat')`

Filter the posts by ID (so the newest post is first), and then grab the distinct ones based on the Chats.

but since order_by and distinct don't match I'm getting the error:

`SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`

So how exactly do I go about doing this? Rawsql? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `distinct` by related model, you must use ordering based of this model:
`Post.objects.order_by('chat', '-id').distinct('chat')`
Also you can look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by)