# Rails + Postgres query for all records that meet a criteria with a unique association ID

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, distinct

I have some code like this:

```
stages.each do |stage|
  start_activity = stage.activities.where('created_at < ?', @start_time).first
  end_activity   = stage.activities.where('created_at < ?', @end_time).first
  # ...
end
```

Which fills my logs with a few screens worth of queries like these:

```
Activity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities"
  WHERE "activities"."stage_id" = $1
  AND (created_at < '2017-01-31 08:00:00.000000')
  ORDER BY id DESC, "activities"."created_at" DESC
  LIMIT 1 
  [["stage_id", 11548]]
Activity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities"
  ...
```

(Activity has a default scoped order of `id DESC`)

So I'm hoping there is a way to fetch all the activities I need per timestamp in a single query. This would reduce my number of from `activity_count * 2` to simply `2`.

Here's what I tried, but I don't think `distinct` is properly being used here.

```
Activity
  .select('DISTINCT ON (stage_id) *')
  .where(stage: stages)
  .where('created_at < ?', @start_time)
  .reorder('id DESC')
```

Which spews out:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (stage_id) * FROM "activities" WHERE "act...
                            ^
: SELECT DISTINCT ON (stage_id) * FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."stage_id" IN (11548, 11549, <more ids snipped>, 12432, 12433) AND (created_at < '2017-01-31 08:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY id DESC):
```

What I mean to do here is to say: give me all activities that have a `stage_id` in an array of `stages`, where the `created_at` date is nearest to (without going over) a timestamp. What I want to get back is a single activity record for every stage in `stages`.

Is it possible to do this in `1` query rather than `stages.count` queries?

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look at your error...

```
ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

...I got to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by).

You need to include 'account_id' in your order function somewhere.

So I think you should be able to do...

```
Activity
  .select('DISTINCT ON (stage_id)')
  .where(stage: stages)
  .where('created_at < ?', @start_time)
  .order(:stage_id, :created_at)
```

Comment: Doing that prevents the error, but then returns zero records :(

Comment: I had a typo above, and was missing a close-quote and close-parenthesis on the second line. Did you copy-paste directly?