# How to construct subquery in the form of SELECT * FROM (<subquery>) ORDER BY column;?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using gorm to interact with a postgres database. I'm trying to ORDER BY a query that uses DISTINCT ON and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) documents how it's not that easy to do that. So I need to end up with a query in the form of

```
 SELECT * FROM (<subquery>) ORDER BY column;
```

At first glance it looks like I need to use `db.QueryExpr()` to turn the query I have into an expression and build another query around it. However it doesn't seem gorm has an easy way to directly specify the FROM clause. I tried using `db.Model(expr)` or `db.Table(fmt.Sprint(expr))` but Model seems to be completely ignored and `fmt.Sprint(expr)` doesn't return exactly what I thought. Expressions contain a few private variables. If I could turn the original query into a completely parsed string then I could use `db.Table(query)` but I'm not sure if I can generate the query as a string without running it.

If I have a fully built gorm query, how can I wrap it in another query to do the ORDER BY I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write raw SQL (including one that has a SQL subquery) that will be executed and the results added to an object using gorm, you can use the `.Raw()` and `.Scan()` methods:

```
query := `
    SELECT sub.*
    FROM (<subquery>) sub
    ORDER BY sub.column;`
db.Raw(query).Scan(&result)
```

You pass a pointer reference to an object to `.Scan()` that is structured like the resulting rows, very similarly to how you would use `.First()`. `.Raw()` can also have data added to the query using `?` in the query and adding the values as comma separated inputs to the function:

```
query := `
    SELECT sub.*
    FROM (<subquery>) sub
    WHERE
        sub.column1 = ?
        AND sub.column2 = ?
    ORDER BY sub.column;`
db.Raw(query, val1, val2).Scan(&result)
```

For more information on how to use the SQL builder, `.Raw()`, and `.Scan()` take a look at the examples in the documentation: http://gorm.io/advanced.html#sql-builder