# How to build this postgresql query in the ORM of sqlalchemist Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with building the query in ORM SQLalchemyst

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT eps.expedient_id,  
eps.first_name,
eps.middle_name,
eps.last_name, 
eps.maiden_name,
eps.person_expedient_id, 
eps.full_name,
doc_type,
doc_number,
cud.claimer_id 
FROM phase_2.expedient_person_search eps 
INNER JOIN phase_2.claimer_user_data cud ON eps.expedient_id = cud.expedient_id 
WHERE eps.first_name = data.first_name AND doc_type = data.doc_type 
ORDER BY order_criteria DESC sorting_order, expedient_id   
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1
```

I have tried in this way, but I always get an error when running the query:

```
Expedients.query.distinct(Expedients.expedient_id).order_by(Expedients.doc_type.desc()).filter_by(**data).offset(page).limit(perPage).all()
```

and show this error:

```
Error: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

My model:

```
class Expedients(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "expedient_person_search"
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'phase_2'}
    expedient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    radicate_number = db.Column(db.String(40))
    doc_type = db.Column(db.String(10))
    doc_number = db.Column(db.String(20),db.ForeignKey('phase_2.claimer_user_data.document_number'))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    middle_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    maiden_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    person_expedient_id=db.Column(db.Integer)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

EDIT 22/03/2019

User model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "claimer_user_data"
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'phase_2'}
    claimer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    expedient_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    document_type = db.Column(db.String(10))
    document_number = db.Column(db.String(20))
    username = db.Column(db.String(250))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(100))
    expedients = db.relationship("Expedients")
```

(have more columns)

and this is mi (**data) data model json:

```
{
  "doc_type": "string",
  "doc_number": "string",
  "first_name": "string",
  "middle_name": "string",
  "last_name": "string",
  "maiden_name": "string",
  "radicate_number": "string",
  "person_expedient_id": "string",
  "page": 0,
  "perPage": 0,
  "orderCriteria": "string",
  "sortingOrder": "string"
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @JeithCarrillo show your model

Comment: model add in post

Comment: Please include the error in your post with proper formatting. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by for an explanation why you get the error.

Comment: @JeithCarrillo what is `data`(`eps.first_name = data.first_name  AND doc_type = data.doc_type`)?

Comment: @danila-ganchar is request data ... in this case for example :

`WHERE eps.first_name = 'ana' AND doc_type = 'CC'`

Comment: @JeithCarrillo can you add `**data`(`.filter_by(**data)`) variable and second model into the question?

Comment: edited. with variables and model.. (the model have more columns, but no necessary )