# Unique text message objects ordered by date query Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, unique

I have a text message model as follows:

```
    class TextMessage(models.Model):
        from_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        to_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        date_of_message = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        message_body = models.TextField()
```

I am trying to return a Django queryset (it **MUST** be a queryset) where the *from_phone_numbers* are unique **AND** the text message is the most recent text message. So for example if I had the text messages:

```
**id**| **from_phone_num** | **to_phone_num** | **date_of_message**|  **Message body** |  
7;"19991112222";"19996667777";"2019-11-13 15:07:53.726911-07";"dupe message 2";
4;"19993334444";"19996667777";"2019-11-13 13:50:05.921257-07";"dsfsdfsf";  
3;"19992222222";"19995552323";"2019-11-13 13:49:18.503679-07";"TEST123";
5;"19991112222";"19996667777";"2019-11-13 15:07:21.834347-07";"dupe message 1";
```

the queryset returned would be:

```
**id**| **from_phone_num** | **to_phone_num** | **date_of_message**|  **Message body** |  
7;"19991112222";"19996667777";"2019-11-13 15:07:53.726911-07";"dupe message 2";
4;"19993334444";"19996667777";"2019-11-13 13:50:05.921257-07";"dsfsdfsf";  
3;"19992222222";"19995552323";"2019-11-13 13:49:18.503679-07";"TEST123";
```

This is the query I have already tried:

```
TextMessage.objects.order_by('date_of_message','from_phone_number').distinct('date_of_message', 'from_phone_number')
```

but it didn't give me the expected results. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Did it raise an exception? Did it order improperly? If so, please either include that stack trace or the incorrectly ordered QuerySet.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. The question is updated!

Comment: Could you show the results that it gave? That would be helpful in determining a pattern and thereby finding the specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below query.

```
 TextMessage.objects.order_by('from_phone_number', '-date_of_message').distinct('from_phone_number')
```

> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY
>   expression(s). So by making the column you use in `distinct` as the
>   first column in the `order_by` should work.

Comment: just sake of curiosity, can you add the equivalent SQL query?

Comment: @JPG just check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) for detail