# SQL MAX funtion where not all atributes are in the group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

So my current problem is that I have two tables that look like this:

```
table1(name, num_patient, quant, inst)
table2(inst_name, num_region)
```

Where I want to find the patient with max quantity per region.

I first had the idea of doing something like this:

```
SELECT num_region, num_patient, MAX(quant)
FROM
  (SELECT num_patient, quant, num_region
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.inst = table2.inst_name) AS joined_tables
GROUP BY num_region;
```

But this doesn't work since either `num_patient` has to be on the `GROUP BY` (and this way it doesn't return the max value by region anymore) or I have to remove it from the `SELECT` (also doesn't work because I need the name of each patient). I have tried to fix my issue with a `WHERE quant = MAX()` statement but couldn't get it to work. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by)

Comment: @MikeOrganek I don't think so. The one you sent uses a ORDER BY, where my question is the grouping of a max function. I don't think the solution is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (num_region), num_patient, quant, num_region
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.inst = t2.inst_name
ORDER BY num_region, quant DESC;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a convenient Postgres extension.  It returns one row per keys specified in the `SELECT`, based on the ordering in the `ORDER BY`.

Being an extension, not all databases support this functionality -- even databases derived from Postgres.  The traditional method would use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT num_patient, quant, num_region,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num_region ORDER BY quant DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table1 t1 JOIN
           table2 t2
           ON t1.inst = t2.inst_name
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of the `DISTINCT ON` question I linked.

```
SELECT distinct on (num_region) num_patient, quant, num_region
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.inst = table2.inst_name
ORDER BY num_region, quant desc
```