# Why does distinct(column) return a duplicate when added with order by?

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

The SQL:

```
select distinct
    h.teacher_id,
    h.last_updated_at,
    c.name
from sometable h 
   inner join class c on h.teacher_id=c.id
   where last_updated_at is not null
   order by last_updated_at desc limit 5;
```

I'm getting duplicate `teacher_id` in response. Where am I going wrong? I wanted to return last updated teacher name and id.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what `distinct` does.  It applies to the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...` returns unique ***rows***. The same teacher can appear many times while other columns differ.

If you want rows to be unique on selected column(s), use `DISTINCT ON`. Like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (teacher_id)
       h.teacher_id,
     , h.last_updated_at
     , c.name
FROM   ...
ORDER  BY teacher_id, last_updated_at DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If you want a different `ORDER BY`, see:

- [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by/9796104?r=SearchResults#9796104)

Comment: Yes I did that too. If teacher_id is not just id, its a unique string id. So in order by when I add teacher_id the entire thing changes.

Comment: @BharatBittu: The linked answer explains every last detail of `DISTINCT ON`.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably see that the `teacher_id` in question has more than one class associated with it. If you need one record per teacher and all classes they lead, you can use something like `STRING_AGG(c.name)` (depending on your version of PostgreSQL). Alternatively, you can return the number of classes they lead with a `COUNT(c.name)`.

In both cases, you will need to `GROUP BY` the teacher’s ID and last update.