# SQL Join with mapping table with NOT condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There is a dimension table like this:

| id | column_a | column_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val_a1 | val_b1 |
| 2 | val_a1 | val_b2 |
| 3 | val_a2 | val_b2 |
| 4 | val_a2 | val_b3 |
| 5 | val_a2 | val_b1 |

I am creating a mapping table to add a new column to the dimension like column_x, here:

| column_a | column_b | column_x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val_a1 | 'Any-Value' | val_x1 |
| val_a2 | val_b2 | val_x2 |
| val_a2 | 'not val_b2' | val_x3 |

How to read the mapping table:

This means for all the rows with vol_a1 in column_a and any value in column_b: column_x will have val_x1.

This means for the rows with vol_a2 in column_a and specifically val_b2 in column_b: column_x will have val_x2.

This means for the rows with vol_a2 in column_a and specifically **NOT** val_b2 in column_b: column_x will have val_x3.

The output will look like:

| id | column_a | column_b | column_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val_a1 | val_b1 | val_x1 |
| 2 | val_a1 | val_b2 | val_x1 |
| 3 | val_a2 | val_b2 | val_x2 |
| 4 | val_a2 | val_b3 | val_x3 |
| 4 | val_a2 | val_b1 | val_x3 |

Can I do it in a single join?
I can obviously break it in multiple CTEs and can do it. What would the most optimal way to do it, if the dimension table is big?

I thought to change the mapping table into this and add priorities with the help of `IF` conditions in the `ON` clause with `OR` Conditions:

| column_a | column_b | column_x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val_a1 | 'Any-Value' | val_x1 |
| val_a2 | val_b2 | val_x2 |
| val_a2 | 'Any-Value' | val_x3 |

But it's giving me duplicates.

I can use SLQ or python to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This might do. Pls. note that there might be more than one mapping record joined to certain dimension records. Having OR in join conditions is not very performant btw.

```sql
select t1.id, t1.column_a, t1.column_b, t2.column_x
from _dimension t1 left outer join _mapping t2
on
  t1.column_a = t2.column_a and t2.column_b = 'Any-Value' OR
  t1.column_a = t2.column_a and t1.column_b = t2.column_b OR
  t1.column_a = t2.column_a and t2.column_b ~* '^not ' 
   and t1.column_b <> regex_replace(t2.column_b, '^not (.+)$', '\1', 'i');
```

About priorities, I would suggest that you add an explicit  `priority_level integer` column in your mapping table. Then the query will look like this:

```sql
select distinct on (t1.id)
    t1.id, t1.column_a, t1.column_b, t2.column_x
from _dimension t1 left outer join _mapping t2
on
  t1.column_a = t2.column_a and t2.column_b = 'Any-Value' OR
  t1.column_a = t2.column_a and t1.column_b = t2.column_b OR
  t1.column_a = t2.column_a and t2.column_b ~* '^not '
   and t1.column_b <> regex_replace(t2.column_b, '^not (.+)$', '\1', 'i');
order by t1.id, t2.priority_level;
```

It may be a good idea to use `null` instead of `'Any-Value'` and `'!val_b'` instead of `'not val_b'` in the mapping table for simplicity.

Comment: Yes, I can change the mapping table. I tried almost similar, but I don't understand how this will take care of the overlap part for 'Val_x2' and 'Val_x3'

Comment: [DISTINCT ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by)  (t1.id) will do that for you and ORDER BY second expression will determine which record will be picked (always the first one in the group).

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a case when statement instead of a join? So your query / view would be:

```
Select id,  
column_a,  
column_b,  
case when column_a = 'val_a1' then 'val_x1' 
when column_a = 'val_a2' and column_b = 'val_b2' then 'val_x2' 
when column_a = 'val_a2' and column_b <>'val_b2' then 'val_x3' 
else -- add your other conditions here 
end as column_x from table
```

In case you need to join, you can do so with a single join on SQL server using case when and an additional column on your mapping table for the values of column_b that you want to exclude..

Let's say this is your new mapping table:

```
| column_a | column_b | column_b_exclude | column_x |
-----------|----------|------------------|----------|
| val_a1   | NULL     | NULL             | val_x1   |
| val_a2   | val_b2   | NULL             | val_x2   |
| val_a2   | NULL     | val_b2           | val_x3   |
```

Your join would look like

```
select * from 
table t 
inner join mapping m 
on t.column_a = m.column_a and 
case when m.column_b is null then t.column_b else m.column_b end = t.column_b and case when m.column_b_exclude is not null then m.column_b_exclude else 'x' end <> t.column_b
```