# Use DISTINCT for 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this Postgres SQL query in which I would like to add DISTINCT:

```
SELECT pairs, a.change_id, user_size, user_mile, b.change_short_name
FROM order_data a
FULL OUTER JOIN changes b
ON a.change_id = b.change_id
ORDER BY a.created_at ASC;
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pairs, a.change_id, user_size, user_mile, b.change_short_name
FROM order_data a
FULL OUTER JOIN changes b
ON a.change_id = b.change_id
ORDER BY a.created_at ASC;
```

I get error: `[42P10] ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list Position: 280`

I need to use DISTINCT for `pairs`, `a.change_id` and biggest `a.created_at`.

What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]!

Comment: You say: `I need to use DISTINCT for pairs, a.change_id` And you are sure you didn't really mean `DISTINCT for pairs, COALESCE(a.change_id, b.change_id)`? Else the `FULL JOIN` doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, and a `LEFT JOIN` would seem more appropriate. Also, does the sort order of the result matter? Or do you just want to pick the oldest row from each set of peers? Please table-qualify all columns and (always) declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: The core issue of your question is this: `I would like to add DISTINCT:`. But we'd rather need to know what you really want to achieve. I don't suppose you just fell in love with the `DISTINCT` key word.

Comment: I have a table who stores several versions of data of temperature measurement. The idea is to execute the query and if we have different data to return result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`. Pls. note the `ORDER BY` clause. Some good examples/discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pairs, a.change_id)
    pairs, a.change_id, user_size, user_mile, b.change_short_name
FROM order_data a
FULL OUTER JOIN changes b ON a.change_id = b.change_id
ORDER BY pairs, a.change_id, a.created_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`. Use `MAX()` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT pairs, a.change_id, user_size, user_mile, b.change_short_name
FROM order_data a
FULL OUTER JOIN changes b
  ON a.change_id = b.change_id
GROUP BY pairs, a.change_id, user_size, user_mile, b.change_short_name
ORDER BY MAX(a.created_at) ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```sql
SELECT pairs, change_id, user_size, user_mile, change_short_name
FROM  (
   SELECT DISINCT ON (pairs, change_id)
          pairs, change_id, user_size, user_mile, b.change_short_name, a.created_at
   FROM   order_data a
   FULL   JOIN changes b USING (change_id)
   ORDER  BY pairs, change_id, a.created_at
ORDER  BY created_at;
```

Note the `USING` clause which merges `a.change_id` and `b.change_id` to  effectively `COALESCE(a.change_id, b.change_id)`.

The outer `SELECT` is to eliminate `created_at` from the result while still sorting by it. It's not entirely clear from the question whether you want that. Your original query does it.

Details depend on undisclosed information: exact table definition, cardinalities, exact requirements. There may be ***much*** faster solutions for many duplicates.

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by/9796104#9796104)