# postgres SQL query to find the recent entry for particular duplicate value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having table with two columns namely hostname and timestamp. Host name will be having many duplicates values as mentioned below. I need to get the timestamp of the last entry of particular duplicated value .In this case,There are duplicate values for both Server AB and CD.but i need to find the duplicate value for Hostname=AB. IN real time this table will be containing many duplicates for hostname.

```
|hostname |timestamp|
|:........|---------:|
|AB       |14Aug2021 11:12|
|BC       |15Aug2021 11:12|
|CD       |16Aug2021 11:12|
|CD      |22Aug2021 11:12|
|AB      |25Aug2021 11:12|
|CD      |26Aug2021 11:12|
```

In the above table I need to get the latest entry of time stamp  for hostname=AB

Comment: Shouldn't `(CD, '26Aug2021 11:12')` be the correct record, as `CD` is duplicate, and this is the most recent such duplicate record?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `LIMIT` query here:

```sql
SELECT hostname, timestamp
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.hostname = t1.hostname AND
                    t2.timestamp <> t1.timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: hi TIm, hostname will be given as input and i have to change the hostname  time to time .it will be helpful if you can give query with using hostname as input

Comment: Then edit your question and show us the real problem and data.

Comment: i have edited my question ..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That should be as simple as

```
SELECT max(timestamp) FROM tab WHERE hostname = 'AB';
```

The aggregate `max` will return the maximal timestamp from all rows matching the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

[distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) is what you need. Please note the `order by` clause.

```sql
select distinct on (hostname) *
from the_table 
where hostname = 'AB'
order by hostname, "timestamp" desc;
```

This particular illustration returns the latest record for hostname 'AB'. You can use other conditions as you wish or no `where` at all which will produce the latest records for all hostnames. If you need just the timestamp for one hostname only then the answer of @LaurenzAlbe should be better.