# Select multiple 'latest' rows from single table of snapshots, one per story snapshotted

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with multiple snapshots of analytics data for multiple stories. The data is stored along with the timestamp it was taken, and the story_id the data is referring to.

```
id: integer auto_increment
story_id: string
timestamp: datetime
value: number
```

and I need to pull out the latest `value` for each story (i.e. each unique storyId) in a list of ids.

I've written a query, but it scales catastrophically.

```
SELECT story_id, value
FROM table
WHERE story_id IN ('1','2','3')
AND id = (SELECT id
          FROM table inner
          WHERE inner.story_id = table.story_id
          ORDER BY timestamp DESC
          LIMIT 1)
```

What's a more efficient way to make this query?

Nice to know:

- story_id has to be a string, it's from an external data source
- story_id and timestamp already have indexes
- there are 2.9M rows and counting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good case for `order by` - [controlled distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by).

```sql
select DISTINCT ON (story_id) 
       story_id, "value"
from the_table
where story_id in ('1','2','3')
ORDER BY story_id, "timestamp" desc;
```

An index on `story_id, timestamp` as @wildplasser suggests will make it scale well.

Comment: Not only is this the simplest query, but it performs the fastest out of all the answers so far :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this, does it improve your performance?

```
SELECT 
  story_id, 
  value
FROM (
      SELECT 
        story_id, 
        timestamp,
        MAX(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY story_id) AS max_timestamp_per_id,
        value
      FROM table)
WHERE timestamp = max_timestamp_per_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A equivalent rewrite of your query using analytic function to get the last `ID` per `story_id` in the `timestamp` order is as below

```
with last_snap as (
select
story_id, value,
row_number() over (partition by story_id order by timestamp desc)  as rn
from tab
)
select story_id, value
from last_snap
where rn = 1;
```

This may work bettwer than you subquery solution, but will also **not scale** for data larger that few 100K rows (better, it will scale the same way as sorting of your full data).

The correct setup for a table with multiple snapshots is a *partitioned table* containing one partition for each snapshot.

The query selects only the data in the *last snapshot* (`snap_id = nnn`)  skipping all older data.

Comment: This is more or less the very definition of `distinct on` semantics.

Answer (score -1):

- Use the proper table definition, including natural key on `(story_id, ztimestamp)` .
- BTW `timestamp` is a data type, better not use it as a column name.
- BTW2: you probably want `story_id` to be an integer field in stead of a text field, and since it is a key field you may also want it to be NOT NULL.

---

```
-- DDL
DROP TABLE story CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE story
        ( id serial not null primary key
        , story_id text NOT NULL
        , ztimestamp timestamp not null
        , zvalue integer not null default 0
        , UNIQUE (story_id, ztimestamp) -- the natural key
        );


\d+ story


EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM story st
WHERE story_id IN('1','2','3')
AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM story nx
        WHERE nx.story_id = st.story_id
        AND nx.ztimestamp > st.ztimestamp
        );
```

---

---

```
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
                                                              Table "tmp.story"
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |              Default              | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('story_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 story_id   | text                        |           | not null |                                   | extended |              | 
 ztimestamp | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              | 
 zvalue     | integer                     |           | not null | 0                                 | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "story_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "story_story_id_ztimestamp_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (story_id, ztimestamp)

                                                QUERY PLAN                                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=1.83..18.97 rows=13 width=48)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on story st  (cost=1.67..10.94 rows=16 width=48)
         Recheck Cond: (story_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::text[]))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on story_story_id_ztimestamp_key  (cost=0.00..1.67 rows=16 width=0)
               Index Cond: (story_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::text[]))
   ->  Index Only Scan using story_story_id_ztimestamp_key on story nx  (cost=0.15..0.95 rows=2 width=40)
         Index Cond: ((story_id = st.story_id) AND (ztimestamp > st.ztimestamp))
(7 rows)
```