# Postgresql Union to combine two table

Tags: postgresql, union

I Have two similar table but new & old.

table01 Old

| id | customer | product | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Cust001 | Soap | 200 |
| 002 | Cust002 | Shampoo | 23 |
| 003 | Cust003 | Ketchup | 30 |

table01 New

| id | customer | product | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | Cust002 | Shampoo | 70 |
| 003 | Cust003 | Ketchup | 50 |

what i want to get on union is id 001 from old table, and id 002 - 003 from new table

| id | customer | product | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Cust001 | Soap | 200 |
| 002 | Cust002 | Shampoo | 70 |
| 003 | Cust003 | Ketchup | 50 |

After i try with union all or simple union it's not show like what i want.
How to get the view like my wanted table use case or what should i do after union?

*now, my real table got hundres transaction id

Answer (score 1):

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1dcfc7446bf0c9d6382c71b516a4c842)
[PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by)

```
WITH cte AS (
(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            customer1
        ORDER BY
            quantity)
    UNION ALL (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            customer2
        ORDER BY
            quantity))
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, customer, product)
    *
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4 DESC;
```

UNION ALL make all the rows from tables is there, then distinct on remove duplicates, using ORDER BY to decide which row is being "saved" in an DISTINCT ON operation.