# Postgres Update with json to record?

Tags: json, postgresql

i try to find a simple solution to update data with the json_to_record statement. I want to update the data every night with a json_array i get by web_craping. Any idea how i can solve the problem when theres a new article?
Thanks a lot :)

```sql
INSERT INTO prices
Select * from
  json_to_record(
    '{"distributor“: "1", "articelnr": 4711,  "price": „700“, "delivery": "too late", "created_on": "2022-09-25 03:14:07"}'
  ) AS x(distributor INT, articelnr VARCHAR, price VARCHAR, delivery VARCHAR, created_on TIMESTAMP)
```

Is it possible to use an update statement in a similar way like:

```sql
UPDATE prices
SET
  json_to_record(
    '{"distributor“: "1", "articelnr": 4711,  "price": „700“, "delivery": "too late", "created_on": "2022-09-25 03:14:07"}'
  ) AS x(distributor INT, articelnr VARCHAR, price VARCHAR, delivery VARCHAR, created_on TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you do not update at all but keep inserting (i.e. insert-only workflow). The table design must be changed with an autogenerated (surrogate) primary key and an index on `created_on`. Then you query the latest record (`order by created_on desc limit 1`) or use [distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by). Keeping the history is free bonus of this approach.

Comment: "*Any idea how i can solve the problem when theres a new article?*" - not sure what problem you are referring to. But how do you identify a "**new** article"? By what criteria do you distinguish that from an existing article (which I suppose you want to update)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check this the next days and will let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [UPDATE syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) it is possible to update a table using a sub-select, e.g.:

```sql
update prices set
(distributor, articelnr, price, delivery, created_on) = 
(
    select * 
    from json_to_record(
        '{"distributor": "1", "articelnr": 4711,  "price": "700", "delivery": "too late", "created_on": "2022-09-25 03:14:07"}'
    ) as x(distributor int, articelnr varchar, price varchar, delivery varchar, created_on timestamp)
)
where distributor = 1 and articelnr = 4711
```

Unfortunately, the sub-select results are not visible in the `WHERE` clause. Hence using the query in the `FROM` section seems more suitable, e.g.:

```sql
update prices p set
    (distributor, articelnr, price, delivery, created_on) = 
    (x.distributor, x.articelnr, x.price, x.delivery, x.created_on)
from (
    select * 
    from json_to_record(
        '{"distributor": "1", "articelnr": 4711,  "price": "700", "delivery": "too late", "created_on": "2022-09-25 03:14:07"}'
    ) as x(distributor int, articelnr varchar, price varchar, delivery varchar, created_on timestamp)
) as x
where p.distributor = x.distributor and p.articelnr = x.articelnr
```

Note, that you need unique columns (typically a primary key) to identify a row to update. Examples assume that they are `(distributor, articelnr)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check this the next days and will let you know :) Right - the combination of distributor and articelnr is unique. I'm relative new to database and backend development. Sorry if my questions are kind of silly :)