# How to get unique results by best position

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large PostgreSQL DB table. From this table I need to take rows grouped by `Car_id` and `position` columns.
The problem is that I have a lot of duplicates and need to take one row with the best `position`.
I wrote a sql example that gave me the correct results, but it needs to be modified. Or how can I do it in a cleaner way?

And I need to choose a unique car_id, with a minimum position, last by date of scrape, of all passed license plate numbers, I am not interested in what particular license plate number will be.

Example of SQL:

```
select
    "eventDate",
    "Car_id",
    min("position") as "carPosition",
    groupArray(concat(toString("scrapedAt"), '_', toString("position"))) as "scrapedAtByPosition",
    groupArray(concat("licensePlate", '_', toString("position"))) as "licensePlateByPosition",
    groupArray(concat(toString("amazonChoice"), '_', toString("position"))) as "amazonChoicesByPosition",
    'organic' as "matchType"
from "Car1_ScrapeHistoryLicensePlate"
         inner join (
             select "Car_id", max("scrapedAt") as "scrapedAt"
             from "Car1_ScrapeHistoryLicensePlate"
             where "licensePlate" IN ('ALPR912', 'JGPD831') and "eventDate" between '2022-08-12' and '2022-09-12'
             group by "Car_id", "eventDate"
         ) as t1 USING ("Car_id", "scrapedAt")
where "licensePlate" IN ('ALPR912', 'JGPD831') and "eventDate" between '2022-08-12' and '2022-09-12'
group by "eventDate", "Car_id"
order by "eventDate" desc;
```

Database records:

```
eventDate  Car_id  licensePlate position scrapedAt
---------- ------  ------------ -------  --------- 
2022-09-10,   1,   APRJSC512,    1,     1660000001
2022-09-10,   1,   APRJSC512,    1,     1660000002
2022-09-10,   1,   PLBQWN035,    1,     1660000003
2022-09-10,   1,   PLBQWN035,    1,     1660000004
2022-09-10,   1,   PLBQWN035,    2,     1660000002
2022-09-11,   2,   APRJSC512,    1,     1660000011
2022-09-11,   2,   APRJSC512,    2,     1660000022
2022-09-11,   2,   PLBQWN035,    1,     1660000033
2022-09-11,   2,   PLBQWN035,    2,     1660000044
2022-09-11,   2,   PLBQWN035,    5,     1660000022
2022-09-12,   3,   APRJSC512,    3,     1660000111
2022-09-12,   3,   PLBQWN035,    3,     1660000222
2022-09-13,   4,   PLBQWN035,    4,     1660001111
2022-09-14,   5,   PLBQWN035,    5,     1660011111
```

Expected result:

```
eventDate  Car_id  licensePlate position scrapedAt
---------- ------  ------------ -------  ---------
2022-09-10,   1,   PLBQWN035,    1,     1660000004
2022-09-11,   2,   PLBQWN035,    1,     1660000033
2022-09-12,   3,   PLBQWN035,    3,     1660000222
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use brilliant [distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by).
The `order by` list of expressions expressions determine which record to be picked for each `car_id`. For each group with the same `car_id` the first one is picked.

```sql
select distinct on (car_id) * -- or the relevant expression list here
from the_table
order by car_id, position, scrapedat desc;
```

[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fNr7aDbn43b8QB2iYTQErL/0)

Comment: Hmm, it looks very simple! With where clauses on `eventDate` and `licensePlate` columns it works

Answer (score 1):

```
select  eventDate
       ,Car_id 
       ,licensePlate 
       ,position 
       ,scrapedAt
from
(
select  *
       ,row_number() over(partition by car_id order by position, scrapedat desc) as rn
from    t
) t
where   rn = 1
```

| eventdate | car_id | licenseplate | position | scrapedat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-10 | 1 | PLBQWN035 | 1 | 1660000004 |
| 2022-09-11 | 2 | PLBQWN035 | 1 | 1660000033 |
| 2022-09-12 | 3 | PLBQWN035 | 3 | 1660000222 |
| 2022-09-13 | 4 | PLBQWN035 | 4 | 1660001111 |
| 2022-09-14 | 5 | PLBQWN035 | 5 | 1660011111 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZynxY4Tj)

Comment: WOW, it is incredible!!! Thanks very much !!

Comment: BTW this is more or less the very definition of `distinct on`.

Comment: also, I added in subquery where clauses by `eventDate` range and in `licencePlate` columns and it works as I expected.