# Only get newest key-value pairs of owner in select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I get a list of values like the following:

| Name | Version | Value | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | 1.0 | 1 | K1 |
| N1 | 1.0 | 1 | K2 |
| N1 | 1.2 | 2 | K1 |
| N1 | 1.2 | 1 | K2 |
| N2 | 1.0 | 0 | K1 |
| N2 | 1.0 | 0 | K2 |

I just need the newest (highest version) key-value pairs of every name.

The result would be in this case:

| Name | Version | Value | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | 1.2 | 2 | K1 |
| N1 | 1.2 | 1 | K2 |
| N2 | 1.0 | 0 | K1 |
| N2 | 1.0 | 0 | K2 |

This is how the statement currently looks like.

I already had to split the results into single key-value pairs.

The reason is, I'm using them in Zoho-Analytics for generating graphs.

```sql
SELECT inside.* FROM 
(SELECT
         "Name",
         Version,
         to_integer(k1) as Value,
         'k1' as key
FROM  "RD" 
UNION
SELECT
         "Name",
         Version,
         to_integer("k2") as value,
         'k2' as key
FROM  "RD"   order by Version, "Name" asc
) as inside
```

Comment: The ORDER BY inside the subquery makes no sense. (Why a subquery? It's not needed.)

Comment: `to_integer` is not an ANSI SQL function, so you can remove that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use [distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) with descending order by `version` to pick the highest one.

```sql
select distinct on (name, key) *
from the_table
order by name, key, version desc;
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mFpknVfZihH7d9b2vtMpr7/1)