# PostgreSQL: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

Let's say I have the following PostgreSQL table called `products`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    label VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    info jsonb NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

Here is some test data. Note my actual table has millions of records.

```
INSERT INTO products (label, info) VALUES ('a', '[1, 2, 3]');
INSERT INTO products (label, info) VALUES ('a', '[1, 2, 3]');
INSERT INTO products (label, info) VALUES ('c', '[1, 2, 3]');
INSERT INTO products (label, info) VALUES ('c', '[1, 2, 3]');
INSERT INTO products (label, info) VALUES ('b', '[1, 2, 3]');
```

I want to write a query that grabs distinct labels and orders the records by the `created_at` field. My first instinct would be to write the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (label) * FROM products ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

However, this fails with the following error:

> ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Looks like I can fix this using SQL subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (label) * FROM products
) AS subquery ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

which generates the following expected result:

```
 id | label |   info    |         created_at
----+-------+-----------+----------------------------
  5 | b     | [1, 2, 3] | 2022-11-14 03:32:23.245669
  3 | c     | [1, 2, 3] | 2022-11-14 03:32:23.242813
  1 | a     | [1, 2, 3] | 2022-11-14 03:32:23.239791
```

Is this the best way to fix this issue? Or is there a faster way to query this data? Note, I mention above how my actual table has millions of records so I want to come up with the best query possible.

Comment: Your last query selects an arbitrary row for each label, then sorts that arbitrary selection by created_at.  If that is what you *want* to do, then that query is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Leading `ORDER BY` expressions must match `DISTINCT ON` expressions (and vice versa):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (label) * FROM products ORDER BY label, created_at DESC;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

It's unclear whether you want `created_at ASC` or `created_at DESC`: you show the latter, but the results you call "expected" match the former - because your "fix" does not do what you seem to think it's doing.

To sort resulting (distinct) rows by `created_at DESC`, you have to run an outer `SELECT` with a different sort order:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (label) *
   FROM   products
   ORDER  BY label, created_at DESC
   ) sub
ORDER  BY created_at DESC;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by/9796104#9796104)

For a big table, be sure to have an index on `(label, created_at)` or `(label, created_at DESC)`, respectively.

> my actual table has millions of records so I want to come up with the best query possible.

There may be (much) faster solutions depending on undisclosed details. Most importantly:

- How many distinct "labels" for how many rows in total?
- Is there a separate table with one row per (relevant) distinct label?
- Do you actually need `SELECT *`, or is `SELECT label, created_at` all you need?

Comment: The query you proposed generates the wrong result. It's not ordered by `created_at` in descending order.

Comment: Consider the additions. Careful not to confound two distinct questions: which row to pick per label, and how to sort resulting (distinct) rows.