# PostgreSQL select distinct JSONB poor performance

Tags: postgresql, subquery, distinct, distinct-on

Let's say I have the following PostgreSQL table called `products` which has millions of records:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    label VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    info jsonb NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

I have a `SELECT` statement targeting this table with several `JOIN`'s that is generating duplicate rows. This appears to be common: [Why do multiple-table joins produce duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786401/why-do-multiple-table-joins-produce-duplicate-rows)

I know I can fix this issue using `SELECT DISTINCT ...`. However, the query is taking several seconds, whereas the vanilla `SELECT ...` query takes milliseconds.

I presume this has to do with the `info` JSONB field, which can be very large. When I remove `info` from the `DISTINCT` calculation by using `SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) ...` then the query is much faster.

However, `DISTINCT ON` breaks some of my queries that use `ORDER BY [non-id field]` due to this condition:

> SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

I've noticed I can fix the error by using subqueries ([good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426689/postgresql-select-distinct-on-expressions-must-match-initial-order-by-expressio#74426829)):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) ...
) ORDER BY [non-id field]
```

Two questions:

- Is passing a JSONB field through `DISTINCT` a known performance problem? I want to make sure my theory is reasonable.
- Is my solution of using subqueries a good solution for fixing the `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions` error? Or is there a better solution I'm not thinking of?

Comment: I have added very specific questions [answering your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74426829/939860). Addressing them would help this new question about performance. Plus (always!) your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

> Is passing a JSONB field through `DISTINCT` a known performance problem?

Passing *any* large column through `DISTINCT` is a known performance problem. `jsonb` isn't special in this regard.

> Or is there a better solution I'm not thinking of?

That depends. You didn't provide requested information, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get by with a single sort and still have good performance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ([non-id column], id) ...
ORDER BY [non-id column], id;
```