# Postgresql: how to get results count with min of a field and unique of b field?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, distinct, min

I have a posgresql table as below:

```
id       session_id       result
1          111               success
2          111               fail
3          111               fail
4          222               fail
5          222               fail
6          222               success
7          333               success
```

There are three sessions in this table, with session ids `111`, `222`, and `333`; Each session has multiple records, but the `session_id` is the same; and the result of the record with the smallest id determines whether that session is successful or failed.

The id `1` and id `4` and id `7` records in the above sample table determine whether a session is successful or unsuccessful.

Now I want get the total of success sessoins and fail sessions, how to write the SQL?
I've tried the below:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id)) min(id) FROM logs WHERE result = success;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id)) min(id) FROM logs WHERE result = fail;
```

I expected the number of successful sessions to be two and the number of failed sessions to be one, but I got the error.

How can I get the number of successful and unsuccessful sessions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) with custom `order by` and conditional aggregation with `filter` clause.

```sql
with t as 
(
 select distinct on (session_id) result
 from logs
 order by session_id, id -- pick the smallest id for the session
)
select count(*) filter (where result = 'success') as success_cnt,
       count(*) filter (where result = 'fail') as fail_cnt
from t;
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uFt7RwLkWpiYbd9r5QmwU1/0)