# Filter timeseries data based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where I store timeseries data:

| customer_id | transaction_type | transaction_date | transaction_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | buy | 2022-12-04 | 100.0 |
| 1 | sell | 2022-12-04 | 80.0 |
| 2 | buy | 2022-12-04 | 120.0 |
| 2 | sell | 2022-12-03 | 120.0 |
| 1 | buy | 2022-12-02 | 90.0 |
| 1 | sell | 2022-12-02 | 70.0 |
| 2 | buy | 2022-12-01 | 110.0 |
| 2 | sell | 2022-12-01 | 110.0 |

Number of customers and transaction types is not limited. Currently there are over 10,000 customers and over 600 transaction types. Dates of transactions ~between customers can be unique and~ will not always align based on any criteria among a customer or transaction type (that's why I've tried using `LATERAL JOIN` — you'll see it later).

I want to filter those records to get customers IDs with the values of the transaction where any arbitrary condition is met. Number of those conditions in a query is not restricted to two — can be anything. For example:

```
Give me all customers who have a buy with value > $90 and a sale with value > 100$ as their latest transactions
```

The final query should return these two rows:

| customer_id | transaction_type | transaction_date | transaction_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | buy | 2022-12-04 | 120$ |
| 2 | sell | 2022-12-03 | 120$ |

The closest I've came to what I need was by creating a materialized view cross-joining customer IDs and transaction_types:

| customer_id | transaction_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | buy |
| 1 | sell |
| 2 | buy |
| 2 | sell |

And then running a `LATERAL JOIN` between table with transactions and `customer_transactions` materialized view:

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer_transactions
  JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
      FROM transactions
     WHERE (transactions.customer_id = customer_transactions.customer_id)
       AND (transactions.transaction_type = customer_transactions.transaction_type)
       AND transactions.transaction_date <= '2022-12-04' -- this can change for filtering records back in time
     ORDER BY transactions.transaction_date DESC
     LIMIT 1
  ) transactions ON TRUE
 WHERE customer_transactions.transaction_type = 'buy'
   AND customer_transactions.transaction_value > 90
```

It seems to be working when one condition is specified. But as soon as subsequential conditions are introduced that's where things start falling apart for me; changing condition to:

```
 WHERE (customer_transactions.transaction_type = 'buy'
   AND customer_transactions.transaction_value > 90)
   AND (customer_transactions.transaction_type = 'sell'
   AND customer_transactions.transaction_value > 100)
```

is obviously not going to work as there is no row that satisfies both of these conditions.

Is it possible to achieve this using the aproach I took? If so what am I missing? Or maybe there is another way to solve that would be more appropriate?

Comment: Does "have a `buy` and a `sell` transaction as their last two transactions" imply a specific order of these two transactions?

Comment: "Dates of transactions between customers can be unique" doesn't make sense to me. Do you mean "the combination of `customer` and `date` is guaranteed to be unique"?

Comment: @SebDieBln no they don't. Also clarified uniqueness of date — what I meant is that is there is a buy transaction on a date it does not mean there will sell transaction on the same date. Or if there is a transaction for one customer it does not imply there will be a transaction on the same date for another

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE with row_number and chech out the last transactios

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT
"customer_id", "transaction_type", "transaction_date",
  "transaction_value",
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "customer_id", "transaction_type" ORDER BY  "transaction_date" DESC) rn
FROM tab1)
SELECT "customer_id", "transaction_type", "transaction_date",
  "transaction_value" FROM CTE
  WHERE rn = 1 
  AND CASE WHEN "transaction_type" = 'buy' THEN ("transaction_value" > 90) 
WHEN "transaction_type" = 'sell' THEN ("transaction_value" > 100) 
ELSE FALSE END 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE c1 
  WHERE c1."customer_id"= CTE."customer_id" and rn = 1
    AND CASE WHEN "transaction_type" = 'buy' THEN ("transaction_value" > 90) 
WHEN "transaction_type" = 'sell' THEN ("transaction_value" > 100) 
ELSE FALSE END ) = 2
```

| customer_id | transaction_type | transaction_date | transaction_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | buy | 2022-12-04 | 120.0 |
| 2 | sell | 2022-12-03 | 120.0 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F62sygHX)

Answer (score 0):

Use [distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) with custom order to select all the latest transactions per customer according to your several criteria (hence the `OR`) - `latest` CTE, then count the number of result records per user using `count` as a window function - `latest_with_count` CTE - and finally pick these that have a count equal to the number of criteria, i.e. all the criteria are honoured.
This may be a bit verbose and abstract template but hopefully would help with the generic problem. The idea would work for any number of conditions.

```sql
with t as
(
 /*
  your query here with several conditions in DISJUNCTION (OR) here, i.e.
  WHERE (customer_transactions.transaction_type = 'buy'  AND customer_transactions.transaction_value > 90)
     OR (customer_transactions.transaction_type = 'sell' AND customer_transactions.transaction_value > 100)
 */
),
latest as 
(
 select distinct on (customer_id, transaction_type) *
 from t
 -- pick the latest per customer & type
 order by customer_id, transaction_type, transaction_date desc
),
latest_with_count as
(
 select *, count(*) over (partition by customer_id) cnt
 from latest
)
select * 
from latest_with_count
where cnt = 2 -- the number of criteria
```