# select a specific row for each group according to a custom logic

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, window-functions, plpython

I have the following table:

```sql
create table  test_table (
    id serial primary key,
    store text,
    price int,
    id_2 text);
insert into test_table (store, id_2, price) values
('a', '11', 100),
('b', '22', 120),
('c', '33', 150),
('d', '33', 120),
('b', '11', 90),
('d', '44', 240),
('a', '22', 80),
('b', '55', 140),
('c', '11', 150) returning *;

select * from test_table tt group by id_2, id order by id_2;
```

I want to create a view/sub-table where for each group by `id_2` (`grouped_rows`), I pick one row according to a custom logic, something like:

```
if 'a' in grouped_rows.store:
  select row where a is present
else if 'c' in grouped_rows.store:
  select row where c is present
...
```

As I understand, window functions work with the values from a partition (same grouping as the previous group-by)

```sql
select store, id_2, count(id_2)  over (partition by id_2) as counts
from test_table tt  order by counts desc;
```

So can I use a custom window function to apply the previous logic, or are any other way to achieve this? until now, i haven't found a way to use a window function to achieve something like this.

As an extra, is it possible to build the selected row, for example, adding price, where the price would be the `min()` of the group (which doesn't have to be from the same row selected by `store`, but it's from the same `grouped_rows`).

```
if 'a' in grouped_rows.store:
  select row where 'a' is present, select min(grouped_rows.price)
else if 'c' in grouped_rows.store:
  select row where 'c' is present, select min(grouped_rows.price)
...
```

Comment: expected output please

Comment: no you can't customize window functions, without changing the source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use `first_value()` window function with proper custom `order by` in the window definition. Yet using [distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) with custom ordering solves your problem easier and better. You can still use `min()` for the price.

```sql
select distinct on (id_2) * 
from test_table 
order by id_2, 
  case store when 'a' then 1 when 'c' then 2 end nulls last;
```

Please note the second (case) expression in the `order by` clause. It is modeling the rule "If there is a row with `store = 'a'` in the same `id_2` group of rows then take it, else if there is a row with `store = 'c'` in it then take it, else take any row of the group".

| id | store | price | id_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 | 11 |
| 7 | a | 80 | 22 |
| 3 | c | 150 | 33 |
| 6 | d | 240 | 44 |
| 8 | b | 140 | 55 |

With `min_price` extra:

```sql
select distinct on (id_2) *,
  min(price) over (partition by id_2) as min_price 
from test_table 
order by id_2,
  case store when 'a' then 1 when 'c' then 2 end nulls last;
```

| id | store | price | id_2 | min_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 | 11 | 90 |
| 7 | a | 80 | 22 | 80 |
| 3 | c | 150 | 33 | 120 |
| 6 | d | 240 | 44 | 240 |
| 8 | b | 140 | 55 | 140 |

Comment: Thanks!. I don't have much experience with sql, so let me ask this basic question: how these 1, 2,etc. in the case expression translates to  pick the row that i want? I understand those aren't indices of the rows, so how those number translate to pick the row where the condition is true?

Comment: This is how `distinct on` works. It orders all the rows by the list of expressions in the brackets and then picks the row that happens to be first from each group with the same values. This is not what you need so you have to further `order by`  _within_ this group so that the first row is the needed one. The `case` expressions returns 1 for the first choice, 2 (or anything > 1) for the second choice and so on. `distinct on` picks the first, i.e. smallest of them. The particular values (1, 2, ...) have no other meaning except that.