# Gather the last entry for a specific metric from multiple fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

### Context

I have this table:

| Time | Metric A | Metric B | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | 1 |
| A | A | B | 2 |
| A | A | C | 1 |
| B | A | A | 1 |
| B | A | B | 2 |
| B | A | C | 1 |

I want to get the last and summarize the table by Metric A, but sometimes Time goes bonkers and GROUP BY Time is not an option.

What I want is to get the last value of Metric B for each Metric A.   Any tips on how to make sure I get the last inserted value for Metric B for Metric A?

### Desired output

| Time | Metric A | Metric B | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | 1 |
| A | A | B | 2 |
| A | A | C | 1 |

Comment: Can you provide the desired result for this test case?

Comment: I want the first three line (Time A) to be queried. For some reasons, GROUP BY is not an option

Comment: But you still haven't explained your desired output based on your sample input. Is the answer 1, or C, or something else? Update the question with the desired output.

Comment: But these are the earliest values for metric B given that time A is before time B, not the latest as written in the question

Comment: OK... My bad.. What I need is the latest data (think I put a Order by TIME desc on it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use rank() or dense_rank() to achieve what you're looking for.

```
create table table1 (
  time timestamp, 
  metric_a varchar(1), 
  metric_b varchar(1), 
  value integer
  );
  
insert into table1 values 
(current_timestamp, 'A','A',1),
(current_timestamp, 'A','B',2),
(current_timestamp, 'A','C',1),
(current_timestamp - interval '10 minutes', 'A','A',1), 
(current_timestamp - interval '10 minutes', 'A','B',2), 
(current_timestamp - interval '10 minutes', 'A','C',1), 
(current_timestamp, 'B','A',2),
(current_timestamp, 'B','B',3),
(current_timestamp, 'B','C',4),
(current_timestamp - interval '10 minutes', 'B','A',2), 
(current_timestamp - interval '10 minutes', 'B','B',3), 
(current_timestamp - interval '10 minutes', 'B','C',4);
```

---

```
select time, metric_a, metric_b, value 
from (
  select *, 
   dense_rank() over (partition by metric_a, metric_b order by time desc) as rnk
  from table1
  )z
where rnk = 1;
```

| time | metric_a | metric_b | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-14T15:13:49.623Z | A | A | 1 |
| 2023-08-14T15:13:49.623Z | A | B | 2 |
| 2023-08-14T15:13:49.623Z | A | C | 1 |
| 2023-08-14T15:13:49.623Z | B | A | 2 |
| 2023-08-14T15:13:49.623Z | B | B | 3 |
| 2023-08-14T15:13:49.623Z | B | C | 4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mjTiPotpsGQQNoM7EPtcKT/4)

Comment: This - clearly correct - is the very definition of PostgreSQL's brilliant `distinct on` with [custom order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by). Have a look at it. Your solution is equivalent to simply `select distinct on (metric_a, metric_b) * from the_table
order by metric_a, metric_b, time desc; `.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Nice, haven't used that before.

Comment: It is _very_ useful and clean, I like it ver much.

Comment: `dense_rank()` would make sense to get *multiple* latest rows per combination if they tie. That doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm: Just plain `DISTINCT ON`, no different order. That link points in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery:

```
select t.* from tbl t where t.time = (select max(t1.time) 
   from tbl t1 where t1.metric_a = t.metric_a and t1.metric_b = t.metric_b)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z10uId4_)

Comment: There's a problem because, thanks as how those tables are loaded, there can some seconds diff between fields that should be got together

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want the latest row for each combination (A,B).
A plain `DISTINCT ON` does that:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (metric_a, metric_b) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY metric_a, metric_b, time DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/srmc339n)

A matching multicolumn index is typically very useful for performance:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (metric_a, metric_b, time DESC);
```

`DISTINCT ON` is typically fastest, too, for ***few*** rows per group. (Which seems to be your case.) See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If `time` isn't defined `NOT NULL`, you'll want to sort `DESC NULLS LAST`. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

Aside: "time" is a bad name for a `timestamp` column, `time` being a different basic type name.