# Postgres Select Distinct On with key-set pagination

Tags: postgresql, go, distinct, go-gorm, keyset-pagination

I have a table in Postgres

| id | title | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | ..... |
| 2 | title2 | ..... |
| 3 | title1 | ..... |
| 4 | title13 | ..... |
| 5 | title4 | ..... |
| 6 | title7 | ..... |
| 7 | title1 | ..... |
| 8 | title1 | ..... |
| 9 | title53 | ..... |
| 10 | title11 | ..... |
| 11 | title1 | ..... |

and I have a Golang app that uses a GORM as ORM

I need to select columns id and title, where title should be distinct, and it should have key-set pagination by id. For example, if page has side 3, I should select

1 - title1
2 - title2
4 - title13

2d page should be

5 - title4
6 - title7
9 - title53

Any thoughts are welcome, even row sql

Comment: You cannot have keyset pagination with `DISTINCT ON` or grouping.

Comment: Your example is either wrong, or needs more explanation.  If you are sorting alphabetically, why is title2 before title13?  If pseudo-numerically, why is title13 before title4?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can first select all unique titles as a set, then get their id from your table. For example:

```
WITH titles AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT title, id FROM my_table
)

SELECT my_table.id, my_table.title FROM my_table
JOIN titles ON titles.id = my_table.id
ORDER BY id -- or by other column
LIMIT 3
OFFSET 3
```

EDIT: if you have large amount of data in this table you can further optimize the query to limit and skip unique titles first then get their id:

```
WITH titles AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT title, id FROM my_table
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 3
    OFFSET 3
)

SELECT my_table.id, my_table.title, .... FROM my_table
JOIN titles ON titles.id = my_table.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is `UNIQUE NOT NULL`, this achieves your objective:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (title)
          title, id
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY title, id
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY id
LIMIT  3
OFFSET 3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O-bYKsNb)

Notably, `DISTINCT ON` cannot be combined with an `ORDER BY` that disagrees on the same query level. See:

- [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by/9796104#9796104)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

But the intermediate step with `DISTINCT ON` disables direct index support. An index with leading `title` field may still be used, but the whole table  (or just index in an index-only scan) has to be processed for every query. Not actually "key-set pagination".

If at all possible, create a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) with an index on `id`. That is, you can afford to reuse the generated result for enough time before having to refresh.

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_tbl AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (title)
       title, id
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY title, id;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mv_tbl_uniq ON mv_tbl (id) INCLUDE (title);
```

The optional `INCLUDE` clause enables index-only scans (after running `VACUUM`, or `VACUUM ANALYZE` on it, unless `autovacuum` has kicked in.)

Depending on data distribution the `DISTINCT ON` query might be optimized further. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

The query now is just:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mv_tbl
ORDER  BY id
LIMIT  3
OFFSET 3;
```