# Query specific element of array in JSON objects in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

Lets assume we have a PostgreSQL db with a table with rows of cars and events as json

```
brand | events
---+-----------------
audi  | JSON Object
ford  | JSON Object
bmw   | JSON Object
...
```

The JSON has the following structure:

```
{
    "type": "events",
    "data": [
        {
            "event": "foo",
            "timestamp": "2024-02-09T14:07:36"
        },
        {
            "event": "foo",
            "timestamp": "2024-02-10T14:07:36"
        },
        {
            "event": "bar",
            "timestamp": "2024-02-11T14:07:36"
        },
        {
            "event": "foo",
            "timestamp": "2024-02-12T14:07:36"
        },
        {
            "event": "bar",
            "timestamp": "2024-02-13T14:07:36"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I query for rows in the table where the following condition holds:

Events for each car should contain a "bar" event.

The output should look like this:

```
brand | last_bar_timestamp
---+-----------------
audi  | Timestamp
ford  | Timestamp
bmw   | Timestamp
...
```

where the "last_bar_timestamp" is the "bar" event for the specific car with the most current date.

Is this possible with the json functions provided by PostgreSQL?

```
                          Thanks!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using a [lateral subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) and `jsonb_array_elements`. I assume that your `events` column type is JSONB rather than JSON.

```sql
with t as
(
 select brand, (j ->> 'timestamp')::timestamp last_bar_timestamp
 from the_table, lateral jsonb_array_elements(events -> 'data') j
 where j ->> 'event' = 'bar'
)
select distinct on (brand) *
from t
order by brand, last_bar_timestamp desc;
```

[DB Fillde](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sejUN3iVUgLgoYo5WkBnu9/1)

Unrelated but this would be way easier and faster with a normalized data design.

**Edit** For "order by last_bar_timestamp only" you need a subquery because `order by brand, last_bar_timestamp desc` determines [which record to be picked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) for each brand, i.e. the latest. The CTE that is there for clarity in the first version is removed.

```sql
select * from 
(
 select distinct on (brand) 
 brand, (j ->> 'timestamp')::timestamp last_bar_timestamp
 from the_table, lateral jsonb_array_elements(events -> 'data') j
 where j ->> 'event' = 'bar'
 order by brand, last_bar_timestamp desc
) t
order by last_bar_timestamp;
```

Comment: How to order the results purely by the "last_bar_timestamp"?

Comment: Answer is updated